# Is there a CSS parent selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select the `<li>` element that is a direct parent of the anchor element?

As an example, my CSS would be something like this:

```
li < a.active {
    property: value;
}
```

Obviously there are ways of doing this with JavaScript, but I'm hoping that there is some sort of workaround that exists native to CSS Level 2.

The menu that I am trying to style is being spewed out by a CMS, so I can't move the active element to the `<li>` element... (unless I theme the menu creation module which I'd rather not do).

Answer (score 3545, accepted):

The W3C's Selectors Level 4 Working Draft includes [a `:has()` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#relational) that provides this capability, among others:

```css
li:has(> a.active) { /* styles to apply to the li tag */ }
```

All major browsers support this selector. Refer to https://caniuse.com/css-has to check if your target browser or browser versions have support for it.

---

You may need to resort to using JavaScript if your target browser does not fully support this feature.

Comment: As of December 2023, all in-support browsers support this pseudo-class.

Comment: It's so nice to see this be available in all browsers. Previously it was quite painful to do this.

Answer (score 346):

You can use the [`:has()` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

[See browser support at Caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

Comment: As @Rodolfo Jorge Nemer Nogueira pointed out, it is possible with sass (scss) by using the & sign. That then gets compiled to the desired css. It would be nice if the next css version supported &

Comment: Actually, I think there is [experimental syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) equivalent to Andrew's statement: `@supports selector(:has(a))`

Comment: @TamusJRoyce ... and what does SASS compile the resultant CSS too? It has to use CSS at the end of the day.

Comment: I had success with `@supports not selector(:has(a, b)) { ... }` to be able to check if a non compatible browser is used, i.e. Firefox at the time of writing. Cfr. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#testing_for_the_support_of_a_selector

Answer (score 183):

I don’t think you can select the parent in CSS only.

But as you already seem to have an `.active` class, it would be easier to move that class to the `li` (instead of the `a`). That way you can access both the `li` and the `a` via CSS only.

Comment: You can't shift the pseudo selector to the list item, as it is not a focusable element. He's using the :active selector, so when the anchor is active he wants the list item to be affected. List items will never be in the active state. As an aside, it's unfortunate that such a selector doesn't exist. Getting a pure CSS menu to be fully keyboard accessible seems to be impossible without it (using sibling selectors you can make submenus created using nested lists to appear, but once the list gains focus it becomes hidden again). If there are any CSS-only solutions to this particular conun

Comment: @Dominic Aquilina Take a look at the question, the OP is using a class, not a pseudo selector.

Answer (score 149):

You can use [this script](https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector):

```css
*! > input[type=text] { background: #000; }
```

This will select any parent of a text input. But wait, there's still much more. If you want, you can select a specified parent:

```css
.input-wrap! > input[type=text] { background: #000; }
```

Or select it when it's active:

```css
.input-wrap! > input[type=text]:focus { background: #000; }
```

Check out this HTML:

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="Name"/>
    <span class="help hide">Your name sir</span>
</div>
```

You can select that `span.help` when the `input` is active and show it:

```css
.input-wrap! .help > input[type=text]:focus { display: block; }
```

There are many more capabilities; just check out the documentation of the plugin.

BTW, it works in Internet Explorer.

Comment: suppose using jquery `patent()` would be faster. This need testing, however

Comment: @Idered It fails when you have CSS declaration of a Selector Subject with no child selector (`#a!` alone throws an error, `#a! p` works), and so the others will not works either because of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined`: see http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/VkVPs/

Comment: @HerrSerker I think #a! is an invalid selector,  what should it select?

Comment: @Idered I don't know. The spec doesn't say it is illegal. #a! should select itself. At least their should be no error in the JavaScript

Comment: Per my comment on the accepted answer, it looks like the polyfill may be required even in the near future after all, because the subject indicator may never be implemented by browsers in CSS.

Comment: How would you then stick an `:after` on that parent?

Comment: Please add the contents of the script here, otherwise this is useless when GitHub is down.

Comment: good approach, but sadly it's [DEPRECATED]

Comment: Why deprecated?

Comment: Could this be used on pseudo selectors [ parent , div and parent::after ], if div is hovered change the parent:after style? 

@Idered

Answer (score 124):

As mentioned by a couple of others, there isn't a way to style an element's parent/s using just CSS but the following works with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$("a.active").parents('li').css("property", "value");
```

Comment: The `<` selector does not exist (verified using jQuery 1.7.1).

Comment: Perhaps that `<`-syntax worked in 2009 but I've updated it (for 2013).

Comment: Even better, use jQuery's built-in [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/): `$("li:has(a.active)").css("property", "value");`. It reads similarly to CSS 4's proposed `!` selector. See also: [`:parent` selector](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/), [`.parents()` method](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), [`.parent()` method](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: And rather than using `.css("property", "value")` to style the selected elements, you should usually `.addClass("someClass")` and have in your CSS `.someClass { property: value }` ([via](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6279001/578288)). That way, you can notate the style with the full power of CSS and any preprocessors you are using.

Answer (score 89):

There is no parent selector; just the way there is no previous sibling selector. One good reason for not having these selectors is because the browser has to traverse through all children of an element to determine whether or not a class should be applied. For example, if you wrote:

```css
body:contains-selector(a.active) { background: red; }
```

Then the browser will have to wait until it has loaded and parsed everything until the `</body>` to determine if the page should be red or not.

The article *[Why we don't have a parent selector](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors)* explains it in detail.

Comment: actually, the selector would make a very fast browser look slow.

Comment: I trust that browser developers would come up with an implementation which is (at least) as fast as the javascript version, which is the one people end up using anyway.

Comment: @Marc.2377 If you try the above example in JS on your website, I'm never going to visit it. On the other side, I'd say that most of the time, you only care about immediate children, so if it was only limited to the immediate children, it'd be a good addition without too much impact.

Answer (score 81):

The pseudo element `:focus-within` allows a parent to be selected if a descendent has focus.

An element can be focused if it has a `tabindex` attribute.

[Browser support for focus-within](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within)

[Tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

**Example**

```css
.parent:focus-within {
  background: hsl(199deg, 65%, 73%);
}

/* demo styles */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
.child {
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  color: white;
  padding: 3rem;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 18px/1.25 sans-serif;
  width: 20ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" tabindex="0">
    Click or Focus on me, my parent will change.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine in my case, thanks! Just a not, the example would be more ilustrative if you change the color to the parent, not to the sibling, this is replace `.color:focus-within .change` with `.color:focus-within`. In my case i'm using bootstrap nav-bar that add the class to the children when active and I want to add a class to the parent .nav-bar. I think this is a pretty common scenario where I own the markup but the component css+js is bootstrap (or other) so I cannot change the behavior. Although I can add tabindex and use this css. Thanks!

Comment: Productive answer! I do want to add a caveat for the copy-pasters among us - __it's generally considered an antipattern to add non-zero tabindexes__ when adding focus to non interactive elements... Just use 0 or it will always tab to that element first regardless of document flow.

I updated the answer to have a tabindex of zero.

Answer (score 70):

There isn't a way to do this in CSS 2. You could add the class to the `li` and reference the `a`:

```
li.active > a {
    property: value;
}
```

Comment: by making the a element display:block you can style it to fit the whole of the li area. if you can explain what style you are looking for perhaps I could help with a solution.

Answer (score 40):

Try to switch `a` to `block` display, and then use any style you want. The `a` element will fill the `li` element, and you will be able to modify its look as you want. Don't forget to set `li` padding to 0.

```css
li {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: ..., background: ..., border-radius: ..., etc...
}
a.active {
  color: ..., background: ...
}
```

Answer (score 36):

The CSS selector “[General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)” could maybe used for what you want:

```
E ~ F {
    property: value;
}
```

This matches any `F` element that is preceded by an `E` element.

Comment: `.component-one:visible ~ body{ background-color: red; }` does not work.

Comment: @F-Natic I am not surprised that does not work. It is not valid CSS (there is no `:visible` pseudo-class in CSS). `body` is also a direct and *only* descendant of `html`.

Answer (score 35):

In the CSS Selectors 4 specification, CSS introduces a new selector called `:has()`, which finally lets us select parents. That means is we’ll be able to target a CSS element that has specific children within it. This is already supported in Safari and is also in Chrome 105. The full support table is shown
[here](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

### Parent Selectors workings

In CSS, if we want to select something, we use selectors that descend the DOM.

For example, selecting a p tag within a div tag looks like this:

```css
 div p {
   color: red;
}
```

Until now, couldn’t really select the `div` tags which had `p` tags within them, though, and this meant we had to resort to `Javascript`. The main reason this wasn’t implemented in CSS is that it’s quite an expensive operation to do. CSS is relatively fast to parse, but selecting parent tags requires a relatively significantly larger amount of processing.

Using the `:has` selector, we can now select `div` elements which have a `p` children, or any normal combination of selectors.

For example, selecting a `div` with a child `p` now looks like this:

```css
div:has(p) {
  color: red;
}
```

This will make any `div` with a child `p` red.

### Combining parent selection with other selectors

Just like any other CSS selector, we can combine this for specific circumstances.
For example, if you want to select only `div` tags which have direct `span` children:

```css
div:has(> span) {
  color: red;
}
```

As the vocabulary of `:has` suggested, it is not just limited to parent selection.

For example, below we can select a `span` which `:has` a sibling `div`:

```css
span:has(+ div) {
color: red;
}
```

Or even, selecting an element which does not have a child, by using the :not() selector.

For example, the following will select any div which does not have a p child:

```css
div:not(:has(p)) {
 color: red;
}
```

## Selecting elements that only contain text in CSS

One very common problem in CSS is that the `:empty` tag does not select elements that contain any text - so sometimes an element can contain one space, and `:empty` will not apply. The `:has` selector gives us the power to select elements that only contain text nodes and no other child elements.

Although this is not the perfect solution for simply `:empty` elements with spaces (as this will select any element with just text and no additional HTML DOM elements) - it does give us the ability to select DOM elements with only text nodes, which was not previously possible. We can achieve this with the following code:

```css
div:not(:has(*)) {
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Not in CSS 2 as far as I'm aware.  CSS 3 has more robust selectors but is not consistently implemented across all browsers.  Even with the improved selectors, I don't believe it will accomplish exactly what you've specified in your example.

Answer (score 26):

You might try to use hyperlink as the parent, and then change the inner elements on hover. Like this:

```css
a.active h1 {color:red;}

a.active:hover h1 {color:green;}

a.active h2 {color:blue;}

a.active:hover h1 {color:yellow;}
```

This way you can change the style in multiple inner tags, based on the rollover of the parent element.

Comment: That is correct, but limits the markup code within the `a` tag to certain elements only, if you want to conform to XHTML standards. For instance, you cannot use a `div` within `a`, without getting a warning of violating the schema.

Comment: In HTML5 it is perfectly fine to put block elements inside links.

Answer (score 26):

This is the most discussed aspect of the **Selectors Level 4** specification.
With this, a selector will be able to style an element according to its child by using an exclamation mark after the given selector (!).

For example:

```css
body! a:hover{
   background: red;
}
```

will set a red background-color if the user hovers over any anchor.

But we have to wait for browsers' implementation :(

Comment: The ("!") feature has been replaced with ':has()' https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#changes-2013

Answer (score 25):

I know the OP was looking for a CSS solution but it is simple to achieve using jQuery. In my case I needed to find the `<ul>` parent tag for a `<span>` tag contained in the child `<li>`. jQuery has the `:has` selector so it's possible to identify a parent by the children it contains:

```
$("ul:has(#someId)")
```

will select the `ul` element that has a child element with id *someId*. Or to answer the original question, something like the following should do the trick (untested):

```
$("li:has(.active)")
```

Comment: Or use `$yourSpan.closest("ul")` and you'll get the parent UL of your span element. Nevertheless your answer is completely offtopic imho. We can answer all of the CSS-taged questions with a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a hack using `pointer-events` with `hover`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
/* accessory */
.parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: gray;
}
.parent, 
.selector {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.selector {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: silver;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
        </style>
        <style>
/* pertinent */
.parent {
    background: gray;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.parent:hover {
    background: fuchsia;
}
.parent 
.selector {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="selector"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14):

Currently there is no parent selector & it is not even being discussed in any of the talks of W3C. You need to understand how CSS is evaluated by the browser to actually understand if we need it or not.

There is a lot of technical explanation here.

[Jonathan Snook explains how CSS is evaluated](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors).

[Chris Coyier on the talks of Parent selector](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

[Harry Roberts again on writing efficient CSS selectors](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/).

But [Nicole Sullivan has some interesting facts on positive trends](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/).

These people are all top class in the field of front end development.

Comment: The `need` is defined by web developers' requirements, whether to have it in the spec is decided by other factors.

Answer (score 14):

There's a plugin that extends CSS to include some non-standard features that can really help when designing websites. It's called [EQCSS](http://elementqueries.com).

One of the things EQCSS adds is a parent selector. It works in all browsers, Internet Explorer 8 and up. Here's the format:

```
@element 'a.active' {
  $parent {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

So here we've opened an element query on every element `a.active`, and for the styles inside that query, things like `$parent` make sense, because there's a reference point. The browser can find the parent, because it's very similar to `parentNode` in JavaScript.

[Here's a demo of `$parent`](http://elementqueries.com/demos/parent.html) and [another `$parent` demo that works in Internet Explorer 8](http://staticresource.com/parent.html), as well as [a screenshot in case you don't have Internet Explorer 8 around to test with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXCWD.png).

EQCSS also includes [meta-selectors](http://elementqueries.com/#meta-selectors): `$prev` for the element before a selected element and `$this` for only those elements that match an element query, and more.

Answer (score 13):

Just an idea for horizontal menu...

#### Part of HTML

```
<div class='list'>
  <div class='item'>
    <a>Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class='parent-background'></div>
  <!-- submenu takes this place -->
</div>
```

Part of CSS

```
/* Hide parent backgrounds... */
.parent-background {
  display: none; }

/* ... and show it when hover on children */
.item:hover + .parent-background {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; }
```

[Updated demo and the rest of code](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/4fyxywee/)

[Another example](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/o4fkL7kv/) how to use it with text-inputs - select parent fieldset

Comment: It's not at all clear to me how you mean to generalize this to some/many/most of the parent selector use cases, or even exactly which parts of this CSS are doing what. Can you add a thorough explanation?

Comment: I did not try to apply this to real world scenarios, that is why I say "Not for production". But I think It can be applied to 2-level menu only with fixed item width. "which parts of this CSS are doing what" - .test-sibling here is actually background of parent item (the last line of CSS).

Comment: Added explanation (css section of jsfiddle, starting from "MAIN PART")... And I was mistaken - there may be any number of sublevels.

Answer (score 12):

The CSS parent selector (also know as the **:has() selector**) has finally landed in Safari TP 137. The feature is currently being implementated in Chrome as well. ([MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:has))

Parent selection is done via the pseudo-class `:has()`.  For example, `div:has(> .child)` will select all `<div>` elements with a child having a `child` class.

Other examples:

Selecting direct parent of an element

```html
<div>
  <p>Child Element</p>
</div>
```

```css
div:has(> p)
```

**Selecting all the parents of an element**

```html
<div id="grandparent">
      <div id="parent">
            <div id="child"></div>
      <div>
</div>
```

The following selector will select both `grandparent` and `parent`

```css
div:has(.child)
```

You can also use it for nested selectors and even with other pseudo classes:

```css
div:has(> :nth-child(10))
```

Other valid CSS operators can be used to customize the query.

Keep an eye on [caniuse.com/css-has](https://caniuse.com/css-has) for browser compatibility.

Comment: could you please help convert $('section:has(h1.heading1)').css('padding', 0); into pure JavaScript?

Comment: @CodeForGood `document.querySelector('section:has(h1.heading1)').style.padding = 0` but it may not work in all browser yet

Comment: your code throws `Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelector: 'section:has(h1.heading1)' is not a valid selector` error

Comment: Minor edit: The selector for selecting both grandparent and parent should be `div:has(#child)` instead of `div:has(.child)`

Answer (score 11):

It's now 2019, and the [latest draft of the CSS Nesting Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting-1/) actually has something like this. Introducing `@nest` at-rules.

> 3.2. The Nesting At-Rule: @nest
>
> While direct nesting looks nice, it is somewhat fragile. Some valid nesting selectors, like .foo &, are disallowed, and editing the selector in certain ways can make the rule invalid unexpectedly. As well, some people find the nesting challenging to distinguish visually from the surrounding declarations.
>
> To aid in all these issues, this specification defines the @nest rule, which imposes fewer restrictions on how to validly nest style rules. Its syntax is:
>
> `@nest = @nest <selector> { <declaration-list> }`
>
> The @nest rule functions identically to a style rule: it starts with a selector, and contains declarations that apply to the elements the selector matches. The only difference is that the selector used in a @nest rule must be nest-containing, which means it contains a nesting selector in it somewhere. A list of selectors is nest-containing if all of its individual complex selectors are nest-containing.

(Copy and pasted from the URL above).

Example of valid selectors under this specification:

```
.foo {
  color: red;
  @nest & > .bar {
    color: blue;
  }
}
/* Equivalent to:
   .foo { color: red; }
   .foo > .bar { color: blue; }
 */

.foo {
  color: red;
  @nest .parent & {
    color: blue;
  }
}
/* Equivalent to:
   .foo { color: red; }
   .parent .foo { color: blue; }
 */

.foo {
  color: red;
  @nest :not(&) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
/* Equivalent to:
   .foo { color: red; }
   :not(.foo) { color: blue; }
 */
```

Answer (score 10):

The W3C excluded such a selector because of the huge performance impact it would have on a browser.

Comment: false. because the DOM is a tree, they have to go to the parent before getting to the child, so the simply just go back one node. o.o

Comment: CSS selectors are a [queue](http://www.snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) so [selector order](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/) is evaluated rather than the document XPath or DOM hierarchy.

Comment: @rgb At least that's what they told us.

Answer (score 10):

Technically there is no direct way to do this. However, you can sort that out with either jQuery or JavaScript.

However, you can do something like this as well.

```
a.active h1 {color: blue;}
a.active p {color: green;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("a.active").parents('li').css("property", "value");
```

If you want to achieve this using jQuery here is the reference for the [jQuery parent selector](http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-parent-selector).

Comment: could you please help convert `$('section:has(h1.heading1)').css('padding', 0);` into pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 10):

Although there is no parent selector in standard CSS at present, I am working on a (personal) project called **axe** (ie. *Augmented CSS Selector Syntax / ACSSSS*) which, among its 7 new selectors, includes both:

1. an *immediate parent* selector `<` (which enables the opposite selection to `>`)
2. an *any ancestor selector* `^` (which enables the opposite selection to `[SPACE]`)

**axe** is presently in a relatively early BETA stage of development.

See a demo here:

```css
.parent {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.child {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 45px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.child.using-axe < .parent {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child using-axe">Here, the axe parent selector turns the outer square red.</div>
</div>


<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```

In the example above `<` is the **immediate parent selector**, so

- `.child.using-axe < .parent`

means:

> any immediate parent of `.child.using-axe` which is `.parent`

You could alternatively use:

- `.child.using-axe < div`

which would mean:

> any immediate parent of `.child.using-axe` which is a `div`

Comment: The project is in an early Beta stage at present. You can (at least currently) activate axe selectors in your CSS styles by including `<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>` at the very end of your html document, just before `</body>`.

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is **NO**; we don't have a `parent selector` at this stage in CSS, but if you don't have to swap the elements or classes anyway, the second option is using JavaScript. Something like this:

```
var activeATag = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a.active'));

activeATag.map(function(x) {
  if(x.parentNode.tagName === 'LI') {
    x.parentNode.style.color = 'red'; // Your property: value;
  }
});
```

Or a shorter way if you use **jQuery** in your application:

```
$('a.active').parents('li').css('color', 'red'); // Your property: value;
```

Comment: or `parentElement`, sameshing - just `document.getElementById().parentElement` etc.

Answer (score 4):

> Any ideas?

CSS4 will be fancy if it adds some *hooks* into *walking backwards*. Until then it is possible (though **not** advisable) to use `checkbox` and/or `radio` *`input`s* to *break* the usual way that things are connected, and through that also allow CSS to operate outside of its normal scope...

```css
/* Hide things that may be latter shown */
.menu__checkbox__selection,
.menu__checkbox__style,
.menu__hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* Old Microsoft opacity */
}


/* Base style for content and style menu */
.main__content {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

.menu__hidden {
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgray;
  /* Make list look not so _listy_ */
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.menu__option {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: block;
  position: static;
  z-index: auto;
}

/* &#9660; - \u2630 - Three Bars */
/*
.menu__trigger__selection::before {
  content: '\2630';
  display: inline-block;
}
*/

/* &#9660; - Down Arrow */
.menu__trigger__selection::after {
  content: "\25BC";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/* Customize to look more `select` like if you like */
.menu__trigger__style:hover,
.menu__trigger__style:active {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: white;
}


/**
 * Things to do when checkboxes/radios are checked
 */

.menu__checkbox__selection:checked + .menu__trigger__selection::after,
.menu__checkbox__selection[checked] + .menu__trigger__selection::after {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

/* This bit is something that you may see elsewhere */
.menu__checkbox__selection:checked ~ .menu__hidden,
.menu__checkbox__selection[checked] ~ .menu__hidden {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* Microsoft!? */
}


/**
 * Hacky CSS only changes based off non-inline checkboxes
 * ... AKA the stuff you cannot unsee after this...
 */
.menu__checkbox__style[id="style-default"]:checked ~ .main__content {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

.menu__checkbox__style[id="style-default"]:checked ~ .main__content .menu__trigger__style[for="style-default"] {
  color: darkorange;
}

.menu__checkbox__style[id="style-one"]:checked ~ .main__content {
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgray;
}

.menu__checkbox__style[id="style-one"]:checked ~ .main__content .menu__trigger__style[for="style-one"] {
  color: darkorange;
}

.menu__checkbox__style[id="style-two"]:checked ~ .main__content {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: red;
}

.menu__checkbox__style[id="style-two"]:checked ~ .main__content .menu__trigger__style[for="style-two"] {
  color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<!--
  This bit works, but will one day cause troubles,
  but truth is you can stick checkbox/radio inputs
  just about anywhere and then call them by id with
  a `for` label. Keep scrolling to see what I mean
-->
<input type="radio"
       name="colorize"
       class="menu__checkbox__style"
       id="style-default">
<input type="radio"
       name="colorize"
       class="menu__checkbox__style"
       id="style-one">
<input type="radio"
       name="colorize"
       class="menu__checkbox__style"
       id="style-two">


<div class="main__content">

  <p class="paragraph__split">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  </p>

  <input type="checkbox"
         class="menu__checkbox__selection"
         id="trigger-style-menu">
  <label for="trigger-style-menu"
         class="menu__trigger__selection"> Theme</label>

  <ul class="menu__hidden">
    <li class="menu__option">
      <label for="style-default"
             class="menu__trigger__style">Default Style</label>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__option">
      <label for="style-one"
             class="menu__trigger__style">First Alternative Style</label>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__option">
      <label for="style-two"
             class="menu__trigger__style">Second Alternative Style</label>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <p class="paragraph__split">
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

</div>
```

... pretty *gross*, but with just CSS and HTML it is possible to touch and re-touch anything but the `body` and `:root` from just about anywhere by linking the `id` and `for` properties of `radio`/`checkbox` *`input`s* and `label` *triggers*; likely someone'll show how to re-touch those at some point.

One additional caveat is that only **one** `input` of a specific `id` maybe used, first `checkbox`/`radio` *wins* a toggled state in other words... **But** multiple labels can all point to the same `input`, though that would make both the HTML and CSS look even grosser.

---

> ... I'm hoping that there is some sort of workaround that exists native to CSS Level 2...

I am not sure about the other pseudo classes, but I `:checked` for pre-CSS 3. If I remember correctly, it was something like `[checked]` which is why you may find it in the above code, for example,

```css
.menu__checkbox__selection:checked ~ .menu__hidden,
.menu__checkbox__selection[checked] ~ .menu__hidden {
 /* rules: and-stuff; */
}
```

... but for things like `::after` and `:hover`, I'm not at all certain in which CSS version those first appeared.

That all stated, please don't ever use this in production, not even in anger. As a joke sure, or in other words just because something *can* be done does not always mean it *should*.

Comment: There has never been a "CSS4" planned, and even CSS3 had been merged into just "CSS" well before 2019.

Comment: Tyler CSS4 is being considered by those that maintain the spec.  Announcement link → https://www.w3.org/community/css4/ Discussion link → https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4770

Comment: That's just the name of a discussion group. There will be no technology called CSS4. CSS Modules are versioned independently and have been for many years now. As the actual CSSWG contributors in that random user's GitHub request have already replied [*and wrote a response about*](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/css4-pros-cons-discussion/), it's not a good idea. Plus that request has been dead for over a year (you can see the GH w3c account has been deleting recent advocacy comments trying to necro it).

Comment: That article is an opinion peace, and overall is a distraction from the spec discussion thread. A handful of off-topic marked comments and one deleted comment does not make intent to _necro_, and I'd expect the Issue to be marked as Closed if the working group where committed to killing CSS4 discussion. It's okay, and a good thing in large projects, that modules are versioned independently; module versions do not conflict with spec versioning.

Comment: It's an opinion piece by a contributing member of the CSSWG extrapolating on her "no" response in the GitHub request, which has languages inactive for over a year. It's safe to say it is not being moved forward with. Module versions *would* conflict massively with spec versioning, as several comments in the thread highlight. Listen, as badly as you want it to be a thing, it's not. It's important to accept that and not confuse readers by mentioning things that don't exist.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot select the parent in CSS only.

But as you already seem to have an `.active` class, it would be easier to move that class to the `li` (instead of the `a`). That way you can access both the `li` and the `a` via CSS only.

Answer (score 3):

At least up to and including CSS 3 you cannot select like that.
But it can be done pretty easily nowadays in JavaScript, you just need to add a bit of vanilla JavaScript, notice that the code is pretty short.

```js
cells = document.querySelectorAll('div');
[].forEach.call(cells, function (el) {
    //console.log(el.nodeName)
    if (el.hasChildNodes() && el.firstChild.nodeName=="A") {
        console.log(el)
    };
});
```

```html
<div>Peter</div>
<div><a href="#">Jackson link</a></div>
<div>Philip</div>
<div><a href="#">Pullman link</a></div>
```

Comment: Eduard Florinescu, could you please help convert $('section:has(h1.heading1)').css('padding', 0); into pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

**This solution uses plain CSS2 rules with no Javascript and works in all browsers, old and new**. When clicked, the child `anchor` tag activates its `active` pseudo-class event. It then simply hides itself, allowing the `active` event to bubble up to the parent `li` tag who then restyles himself and reveals his anchor child again with a new style. The child has styled the parent.

Using your example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="listitem">
        <a class="link" href="#">This is a Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now apply these styles with the `active` pseudo-class on `a` to restyle the parent `li` tag when the link is clicked:

```
a.link {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

li.listitem {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* When this 'active' pseudo-class event below fires on click, it hides itself,
triggering the active event again on its parent which applies new styles to itself and its child. */

a.link:active {
    display: none;
}

.listitem:active {
    background-color: blue;
}

.listitem:active a.link {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

You should see the link with a green background now change to the list item's blue background on click.

[image]

turns to

[image]

on click.

Answer (score 2):

Changing parent element based on child element can currently only happen when we have an `<input>` element inside the parent element. When an input gets focus, its corresponding parent element can get affected using CSS.

Following example will help you understand using `:focus-within` in CSS.

```css
.outer-div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 50px;
  float: left
}

.outer-div:focus-within {
  background: red;
}

.inner-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    I want to change outer-div(Background color) class based on inner-div. Is it possible?
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused.` It [works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) with every element, not just `input`

Answer (score 2):

There no css (and therefore in css preprocessors) parent selector due to "The major reasons for the CSS Working Group previously rejecting proposals for parent selectors are related to browser performance and incremental rendering issues."

Answer (score 1):

I'd hire some JavaScript code to do that. For example, in React when you iterate over an array, add another class to the parent component, which indicates it contains your children:

```
<div className={`parent ${hasKiddos ? 'has-kiddos' : ''}`}>
    {kiddos.map(kid => <div key={kid.id} />)}
</div>
```

And then simply:

```
.parent {
    color: #000;
}

.parent.has-kiddos {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to a similar (but not I feel exactly the same) question which has been closed in favor of this question so I put an answer to [How to change the border color when input is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69682775/how-to-change-the-border-color-when-input-is-checked?noredirect=1#comment123177057_69682775) here.

As it is not possible to style a parent depending on its child's status using pure CSS, this snippet alters the HTML so that there is an empty span element immediately following the input elements. This span element does nothing until the input is hovered at which point it displays itself and expands to fit the same size as the ancestor which has position set. This is the label itself, not the input. Hence the border (shadow) shows as if it is on the label.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.OuterField {
  display: flex;
}

.listLabel {
  padding: 8px 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 32%;
  margin: 1%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="radio"]~span {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked~span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterField">
  <label for="List1" class="listLabel">List 1
        <input type="radio" id="List1" name="list" value="List1">
        <span></span>
     </label>
  <label for="List2" class="listLabel">List 2
         <input type="radio" id="List2" name="list" value="List2">
         <span></span>
     </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1) but what if there is only `border` without `box-shadow` . How to center than , tried to change `top: -2px` `left: -2px` `width: 102%` `height: 112%` on `span` tag . It worked but on some screen sizes only and don't overlap over black border in all screen sizes . Do I have to give absolute values or there are work around this too . Again thanks for help really appreciate .

Comment: Found a work around a that could be using `width: calc(100% + 4px);` `height: calc(100% + 4px);` with `top: -2px` `left: -2px`

Comment: Glad you have something that works. Yes, it is hard to get an absolute placed element exacty at the same spot as another element to get something like a thin border exactly aligned - even if the line-up is exact CSS-wise the underlying screen pixels may show (as there can be several screen pixels to one CSS pixel) so your solution is a practical one.