# Set different background image dependent on match of child element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can I set a different background-image CSS attribute to my `<BODY>` tag depending on successful match of a found child `<div class="template" />` element?

I know of the CSS selector `BODY>.template` but that alters the `template` class where an immediate parent match of `BODY` exists, I want to control `BODY` if `template` exists as a child.

I would like to do this purely in CSS, not with any jQuery or anything, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible with pure CSS. You can't influence a parent element based on a child element. The *Cascading* in CSS only goes in one direction. :)

If you can you should add a different id or class to `<body>` to do this.