# Change hover style if any child is disabled

Tags: html, background, html-table, hover

I have a table, with a pretty nice style. Td and th elements, on hover, change their background color. However, if there is a disabled element in that row, it still displays lighter colors than things with disabled elements in them should look. Does anyone know a way to change the hover background if there is a disabled element inside? I can use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably approach the problem by adding a class to the hovered item to modify its behavior when you disable child elements, as css won't let you set styles on a parent object based on properties of their children.  Check out this post:
[Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Comment: That link helped me! Thanks a lot!