# how to make presentation changes to an element post hover effect

Tags: html, css

HI friends..

In a menu suppose there is an item MAIN that has drop down fro its sub categories (sub1, sub2, sub3,...). Now when mouse :hovers over MAIN I can do what ever I want. But when mouse hovers over any of its sub categories, say sub1, I want MAIN to look bold and of a particular. How can I achieve this using CSS.

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In all brevity, *[you can't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Limitations)*. There's no such thing as a `parent` selector in CSS, even though it has been discussed in the past. But if you consider the `C` in CSS carefully, a parent selector doesn't make much sense in any case.

Here's another question which deals with a related/similar issue: [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)