# Adding an arrow to a list-item

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add a right arrow for my sub menus (similar to ddsmoothmenu):

[image]

My sub menus have a class `sub-menu`.

**Here is my code**

```
<div id="centeredmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Cat1</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Cat2</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Cat3</a>
    <ul class='sub-menu'>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Category</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub Category</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I add an arrow besides "Cat3"?

Comment: What do you mean by arrow? Something like this `→`? And check your syntax :)

Comment: An arrow pointing towards bottom, and where is the Syntax mistake?

Answer (score 1):

that arrow is basically an image which is set as background for those `<li>`s where you need it with `no-repeat` and `right 0`  property

for example

**MARK-UP**

```
<ul>
   <li class="arrow"></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li.class{
   background:#000000 url(/path/to/arrow.jpg) no-repeat right 0;
}
```

now only for first element the arrow will be visible

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css for that select your li as below,

```
#centeredmenu > ul li{
   background:url(../img/arrow.png) right center;
}
```

**Comment Response**

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrEuB/2/)

Comment: Is this only applies to `sub-menus` ?

Comment: @XeBii no it will apply to cat1 cat2 and cat3

Comment: @XeBii see edited answer i have edited code as per your comment

Comment: but i only want to apply on cat3 which has a sub menu

Comment: i suppose this will only applies to cat3, what if i also add more Categories with sub menus :(

Comment: @XeBii [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281556/is-there-a-css-way-to-add-an-arrow-if-a-ul-has-a-ul-child)

Comment: yes, i have seen this question before posting my own, but i don't know which answer should be applied

Comment: @XeBii the answer with 39 upvote