# Style the <li> that has child elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-lists

I'm trying to create a top menu with a dropdown submenu function.
I want to target the list items witch have a submenu (child element) attached to it. So that i can style them with a different color list style etc.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul><div id="logo">
            <img src="images/design/logo.png" alt="Logo for responsive template" />
        </div>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Parrent Link
            <ul>
                <li>Child Link</li>
                <li>Child Link</li>
                <li>Parrent Link
                    <ul>
                        <li>Child Link</li>
                        <li>Child Link</li>
                        <li>Child Link</li>
                        <li>Child Link</li>
                        <li>Child Link</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Gallery</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

So each Parrent link get another style than the rest.

Comment: `nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li { ... } `?

Comment: How do you mean like this? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/6uk2x/)

Comment: Best solution would be to give the parent `<li>'s` a class

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281556/is-there-a-css-way-to-add-an-arrow-if-a-ul-has-a-ul-child

Comment: @Legarndary Take a look at my solution. Is it helpful?

Comment: @ItayGal Yes, it was very helpfuf, it does the trick.
If somebody else wanne use this but not wanna target the first parrent just replace "if(parent.is('li')){" with "if(parent.is('ul li ul li')){"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with JQuery: **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/wW5S5/2)**

```
$(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){   
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        if(parent.is('li')){
            parent.addClass("colored");
        } 
    })
});
```

This solution assumes that your HTML is valid and you use `<ul>` and `<li>` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select an element based in descendent elements. Then you can't have a selector like this:

> select all `<li>` tags that contain an `<ul>` tag

In the other way you can

> select all `<ul>` tags inside a `<li>` tag

The best you can do is assign a class:

```
<li>Child Link</li>
   <li>Child Link</li>
   <li class="sub">Parrent Link
      <ul>
        <li>Child Link</li>
        <li>Child Link</li>
        <li>Child Link</li>
        <li>Child Link</li>
        <li>Child Link</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: It's a shame. If only we could have XPath in CSS, that'd be awesome. `//li[./ul]`

Answer (score 0):

I Would change the ul.class every time i make a new list.

so that, if the ul li has children, it will change automatically, if i want to have children there.

Answer (score -3):

You just have to use CSS selectors as follows:

```
ul > li > li {
   // your css code here
}
```

You havethe official documentation in the [W3C site](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

No need tu use `id's` or `class` tags

Comment: With this you target all `li` direct childs of an `ul` tag . Not all `li` elements with an `ul` inside. OP wants *the list items witch have a submenu (child element)*

Comment: You are right, sorry! I did not understand the question well, I editted my answer so now it targets the list elements