# CSS: Select a tag that is a parent of a parent of a tag with the class I want

Tags: css, css-selectors

Basically is what is says in the tin.

I have an input tag and independent javascript to control it. When they user is inserting data it changes one of its' classes automatically so that its color is changed by CSS which is defined elsewhere Until then everything is ok. Next: I want the whole div that contains that input to change color so that the user can be warned when something is wrong. There's a problem here: How can I select that div I want to select only using CSS?
Here's some code that works for the input:

```
input.wrongVal {
    border-color: red;
    background-color: red;
}
input.wrongVal:active{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Here's the relevant code from the page:

```
<div class="infoinputContainer">
    <p class="inputLine">
        <span>
            <input type="text" id="data">
            <label for="data">Data info</label>
        </span>

    </p>

</div>
```

How can I, with only CSS, select for styling the div shown here (and no other div) with, for instance, another background?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with CSS. What you can do however is use Javascript to either change the class of the div container or wrap the div container into another div.

```
<div class="infoinputContainer invalid">
    <p class="inputLine">
        <span>
            <input type="text" id="data">
            <label for="data">Data info</label>
        </span>

    </p>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="invalidInput">
  <div class="infoinputContainer">
    <p class="inputLine">
        <span>
            <input type="text" id="data">
            <label for="data">Data info</label>
        </span>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try altering the javascript so that it searches for the parent with a specific class and control it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Not with pure CSS.

CSS selectors only select/target children or descendants for performance purposes: if you could target `:parent` (like in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/)) the browser would have to wait to render *any* of the page until it had processed *all* child nodes.

You'll have to use JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't with just css.

What are you using to change the class when a user enters information? If it's javascript, you can use that to change the class of the parent (or grandparent) as well.

Comment: The javascript is a generic code. It does not know where it should apply the class if it is not the input element. It seems like the js code must be changed then. That means that there is really no way with CSS?

Comment: @brunoais No, you can't select parent elements with css, you'll have to modify your javascript / add some new javascript.