# How to change background color of table row (tr) when input is ":focus"?

Tags: css

My **HTML**:
    `<tr><td>Text</td><td><input type="text" value=""></td></tr>`

My **CSS**:
    `input:focus tr{ background-color:#fff;}`

I want to highlight the row in white when I'm writing text in the input field. I know "tr" is before "input", but is this possible to do in any way?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, sadly. See: [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child/45530#45530)

Here's how you could do it, though: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/udzcp/

Comment: Thank you very much for this link! You just saved me alot of time

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I edited my post to include an example of how you might do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Using JQuery, it is very possible. Observe:

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="20">
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td height="50" width="100" id="somename"><input type="text" value="" id="mirza"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a&nbsp;</td><td>1&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a&nbsp;</td><td>1&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a&nbsp;</td><td>1&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a&nbsp;</td><td>1&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a&nbsp;</td><td>1&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlightedRow { background-color: orange; }
```

**Jquery**

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlightedRow');
});

$('input').blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('highlightedRow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there's no way to style the parent element with CSS, so you'll have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is good for when you are generating a lot of similar rows (looping through large datasets, etc):
Script:

```
function rowSet(data_id){
    document.getElementById('row_' + data_id).style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
function rowReset(data_id){
    document.getElementById('row_' + data_id).style.backgroundColor = '';
}
```

Body:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr id="row_#data_id#">
                <td><input name="input1_#data_id#" onFocus="rowSet(#data_id#);" onBlur="rowReset(#data_id#);"></td>
                <td><input name="input2_#data_id#" onFocus="rowSet(#data_id#);" onBlur="rowReset(#data_id#);"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

You could also use currentRow, or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

This jquery code should do it:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $('tr').css("background-color", "#c00");
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vGEPb/2/)

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/9mR95/ That code will highlight all rows and not just the parent of the input element when one is selected and won't un-higlight the row after blur.