# Vertical table head and clickable cells

Tags: html, css

I have created a table with vertical test in the head, but i fail to make the cells to be clickable.

The table is used to document file formats that are used in our system. As I have implement it now, it is possible to click on the text link to go to the documentation. But, how do I do so that it is able to click anywhere in a cells. To be even clearer, I want the background color of the cell to change when you move the mouse over it.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: White;
  overflow-x: auto;
  _overflow: auto;
}
table.form a {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
table.form a:hover {
  color: SteelBlue;
}
table.form {
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.form th,
table.form td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  min-width: 9px;
}
table.form td {
  width: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}
th:not(.rotate) {
  text-align: left;
}
th.rotate {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
th.rotate > div {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
th.rotate > div >span {
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  /* old syntax. IE */
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -moz-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  /* new syntax */
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <table class="form">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=10>Short reference</th>
        <th colspan=20>External Identity</th>
        <th colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Cathegory</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=17>Connection</th>
        <th colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Filter time</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Indication type</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>C=Command</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>L=Overload check</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Overload max</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=22 rowspan=2>&nbsp;</th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Equipped spare = 1</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Non-equip. spar=1</span>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=3 class="rotate">
          <div><span><a href="#formtype">Form type</a></span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span><a href="#sheet">Sheet</a></span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span><a href="#line">Line</a></span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=3 class="rotate">
          <div><span><a href="#terminalno">Terminal no</a></span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=6>
          <div><span><a href="#system">System</a></span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=14>
          <div><span><a href="#pointcode">Point code</a></span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=3 class="rotate">
          <div>
            <span>Type of input</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div>
            <span>Bus address (hex)</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div>
            <span>Channel no</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=10>Type of Board</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
        <th>14</th>
        <th>15</th>
        <th>16</th>
        <th>17</th>
        <th>18</th>
        <th>19</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>21</th>
        <th>22</th>
        <th>23</th>
        <th>24</th>
        <th>25</th>
        <th>26</th>
        <th>27</th>
        <th>28</th>
        <th>29</th>
        <th>30</th>
        <th>31</th>
        <th>32</th>
        <th>33</th>
        <th>34</th>
        <th>35</th>
        <th>36</th>
        <th>37</th>
        <th>38</th>
        <th>39</th>
        <th>40</th>
        <th>41</th>
        <th>42</th>
        <th>43</th>
        <th>44</th>
        <th>45</th>
        <th>46</th>
        <th>47</th>
        <th>48</th>
        <th>49</th>
        <th>50</th>
        <th>51</th>
        <th>52</th>
        <th>53</th>
        <th>54</th>
        <th>55</th>
        <th>56</th>
        <th>57</th>
        <th>58</th>
        <th>59</th>
        <th>60</th>
        <th>61</th>
        <th>62</th>
        <th>63</th>
        <th>64</th>
        <th>65</th>
        <th>66</th>
        <th>67</th>
        <th>68</th>
        <th>69</th>
        <th>70</th>
        <th>71</th>
        <th>72</th>
        <th>73</th>
        <th>74</th>
        <th>75</th>
        <th>76</th>
        <th>77</th>
        <th>78</th>
        <th>79</th>
        <th>80</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Q</td>
        <td>I</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<h3 id="formType">Form type</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Form type
</p>

<h3 id="sheet">Sheet</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Sheet
</p>

<h3 id="line">Line</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Line
</p>

<h3 id="terminalno">Terminal no</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Terminal no
</p>

<h3 id="line">Line</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Line
</p>

<h3 id="system">System</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for System
</p>

<h3 id="pointcode">Point code</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Point code
</p>
```

Comment: You have the links only in the `th` do you mean the click only on th or its `td` as well

Comment: The links is only in <th>.

Comment: So you want the color to change only on the `th`?

Comment: Yes, but I also want the link to be clickable anywhere in the cell.

Comment: Ok got you.. let me update my answer

Comment: Its not possible to achieve this functionality without using jquery or javascript

Comment: @selvassn it is..

Comment: parent selector is not available in css. How will you do it ?

Comment: @magol : Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306738/change-background-of-parent-div-on-hover

Comment: @selvassn how do I use jQuery to make the entire cells clickable? Changing the background color is only a minor issue.

Comment: @selvassn see my answer, Parent selctor is not required here, You need to just make sure the anchor tag takes the whole space available in `th`..

Comment: @magol updated my answer. have a check

Comment: @RajshekarReddy now all the "th" background color was changed to yellow. My understanding was only the "th" which is having <a> should have the background on hover

Comment: @selvassn i mentioned that in the answer itself..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** remove all the extra content in your `th` and make sure it has only the anchor tag as its child. And now stretch the anchor tag to occupy full space of the `th`, This way clicking anywhere on the `th` actually means clicking the `a` tag which works as you expected.

CSS used

```
table.form th:hover { 
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
th.rotate > a {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

To change the color of only the `th` that has links in it change the selector to

```
table.form th > a:hover {
```

HTML changed to

```
 <th colspan=3 class="rotate">
    <a href="#formtype">Form type</a>
 </th>
```

from

```
 <th colspan=3 class="rotate">
   <div><span><a href="#formtype">Form type</a></span>
   </div>
  </th>
```

Also note you have a small typo here in the `href` it should be `formType` instead of `formtype`.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: White;
  overflow-x: auto;
  _overflow: auto;
}
table.form a {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
table.form a:hover {
  color: SteelBlue;
}
table.form {
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.form th,
table.form td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  min-width: 9px;
}
table.form td {
  width: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}
th:not(.rotate) {
  text-align: left;
}
th.rotate {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
th.rotate > div {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
th.rotate > div >span {
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  /* old syntax. IE */
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -moz-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  /* new syntax */
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table.form th:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
th.rotate > a {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <table class="form">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=10>Short reference</th>
        <th colspan=20>External Identity</th>
        <th colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Cathegory</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=17>Connection</th>
        <th colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Filter time</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Indication type</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>C=Command</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>L=Overload check</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Overload max</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=22 rowspan=2>&nbsp;</th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Equipped spare = 1</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th rowspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div><span>Non-equip. spar=1</span>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=3 class="rotate">          
           <a href="#formType">Form type</a>      
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 class="rotate">
          <a href="#sheet">Sheet</a>      
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 class="rotate">
          <a href="#line">Line</a>          
        </th>
        <th colspan=3 class="rotate">
          <a href="#terminalno">Terminal no</a>
        </th>
        <th colspan=6>
          <a href="#system">System</a>          
        </th>
        <th colspan=14>
          <a href="#pointcode">Point code</a>
        </th>
        <th colspan=3 class="rotate">
          <div>
            <span>Type of input</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div>
            <span>Bus address (hex)</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=2 class="rotate">
          <div>
            <span>Channel no</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan=10>Type of Board</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
        <th>14</th>
        <th>15</th>
        <th>16</th>
        <th>17</th>
        <th>18</th>
        <th>19</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>21</th>
        <th>22</th>
        <th>23</th>
        <th>24</th>
        <th>25</th>
        <th>26</th>
        <th>27</th>
        <th>28</th>
        <th>29</th>
        <th>30</th>
        <th>31</th>
        <th>32</th>
        <th>33</th>
        <th>34</th>
        <th>35</th>
        <th>36</th>
        <th>37</th>
        <th>38</th>
        <th>39</th>
        <th>40</th>
        <th>41</th>
        <th>42</th>
        <th>43</th>
        <th>44</th>
        <th>45</th>
        <th>46</th>
        <th>47</th>
        <th>48</th>
        <th>49</th>
        <th>50</th>
        <th>51</th>
        <th>52</th>
        <th>53</th>
        <th>54</th>
        <th>55</th>
        <th>56</th>
        <th>57</th>
        <th>58</th>
        <th>59</th>
        <th>60</th>
        <th>61</th>
        <th>62</th>
        <th>63</th>
        <th>64</th>
        <th>65</th>
        <th>66</th>
        <th>67</th>
        <th>68</th>
        <th>69</th>
        <th>70</th>
        <th>71</th>
        <th>72</th>
        <th>73</th>
        <th>74</th>
        <th>75</th>
        <th>76</th>
        <th>77</th>
        <th>78</th>
        <th>79</th>
        <th>80</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Q</td>
        <td>I</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<h3 id="formType">Form type</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Form type
</p>

<h3 id="sheet">Sheet</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Sheet
</p>

<h3 id="line">Line</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Line
</p>

<h3 id="terminalno">Terminal no</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Terminal no
</p>

<h3 id="line">Line</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Line
</p>

<h3 id="system">System</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for System
</p>

<h3 id="pointcode">Point code</h3>
<p>
  Documentation for Point code
</p>
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing, I begin to give up if it was possible. And with cleaner code!
If you can fix the alignment in the cells, your answer is perfect :-)

Comment: @magol seems like that's an drawback of this approach. I am trying it anyways. Give me some time.

Comment: Surprise! One more problem is that it do not works perfect in IE :-(

Comment: @magol hmmm that name (IE) itself brings me pain. Why dont you go with jquery approach?

Comment: Sorry I ruined your day. Forget I said anything, IE is not important

Comment: @magol that's the spirit :D ... IE is a pain bro

Comment: @magol I am still trying, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @magol any luck with aligning the text?