# change css for parent div when hover on link

Tags: javascript, joomla, hover

I tried this solution but am missing something: [change background of parent div on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306738/change-background-of-parent-div-on-hover)

Here is my html:

```
<div class="box">
    <h3 class="page-header item-title">                                              
          <a class="titlelink" href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;id=11&amp;Itemid=234">
                Modeling</a>
```

This is what I tried to use in an override here: /templates/shaper_helixultimate/html/com_content/category/default_children.php

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
$('.box > .titlelink').hover(function(){
$(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
})
    });
');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5hf8qdc/

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.box > .titlelink').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <h3 class="page-header item-title">
    <a class="titlelink" href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;id=11&amp;Itemid=234">
                    Modeling</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: why not simply use css? `.box a.titlelink:hover{ /* your hover css */ }`

Comment: @Kinglish, there are no parent selectors with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `.box > .titlelink` looks for a parent-child relationship. You don't have that.

Use `.box .titlelink` instead.

```js
$('.box .titlelink').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.hover {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <h3 class="page-header item-title">
    <a class="titlelink" href="/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;id=11&amp;Itemid=234">
                    Modeling</a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @isherwood mentioned, the solution you linked to uses a different structure than what you have. The `>` in CSS selectors specifies that you're targeting a *direct child*, while just leaving a space between the two selectors looks for *any descendant*.

```css
.box > .titlelink {
  /* targets where .titlelink is a child of .box */
}

.box .titlelink {
  /* targets where .titlelink is a descendant of .box */
}
```

If you want to use a strict CSS selector like the solution you referenced, you could do:

```js
$('.box > .item-title > .titlelink').hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Although this will add the `hover` class to the `.item-title` element, not to the `.box` element. Assuming that you specifically want target the `.box` ancestor of whatever you're listening for the `hover` event on, then you want:

```js
$('.box > .item-title > .titlelink').hover(function(){
  $(this).parents('.box').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

since jQuery's [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method allows you to pass a selector to target a specific ancestor, travelling multiple levels up through the tree.