# css3 webkit animation stop on div:hover

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

I try to make an animation with webkit-animation and @-webkit-keyframes. I have a div animated  with child div inside.

And i would stop the webkit-animation of the parent when my mouse is over a child.

Any Examples ?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no parent selector in CSS, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child/45530#45530). You will have to use a bit of javascript to select the parent and tell it to pause.

The pause declaration in CSS goes like this:

```
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused | running;
```

The javascript (jQuery, in this case) would look something like this:

```
$(".child").hover(
  function(){
    $(this).parent().css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "paused");
},
  function(){
    $(this).parent().css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "running");
});
```

See a live demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UFepV/

Comment: I know this question and answer are a bit old, but just in case my thinking is wrong: couldn't you do, in the CSS, `.child:hover{ -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; }`? Would that work without having to resort to Javascript?

Comment: No, because you're telling the child to stop, while what is being animated is the parent. The child in essence doesn't even "know" it's being animated.

Comment: You know, I totally missed the `.parent()` call in the hover function. Maybe one day ancestor selectors will become available, but until then I imagine this is the only way.

Answer (score 8):

If you use a more complex label you can achieve this without Javascript.  I used 
`.parent:hover .child { -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; }` and it worked perfectly.