# how to use the CSS contains-element selector with input elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Netbeans, my IDE, marks this CSS as incorrect, but I can't tell the problem. I can't find anything that says contains-element is specific to CSS3, but the styling doesn't show up in Firefox or Opera.

CSS:

```
span:contains-element(input[type="radio"]) {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span><input type="radio" name="amount" value="Cash amount"/>Cash amount</span>
```

Comment: Found it: http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor//_distrib/doc/csssupport/containing_child.html It appears to be an XMLmind extension...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:contains-element` isn't a CSS selector, as far as I know. Where did you get it from?

The fact that it doesn't exist explains why it doesn't work in browsers and Netbeans marks it as incorrect.

That looks like an attempted "parent selector" (maybe from some JavaScript library?) and as always, there is no parent selector [in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/):

- [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)
- [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

---

As pointed out by @Šime Vidas, that selector is specific to this product:

http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor//_distrib/doc/csssupport/containing_child.html

> This document describes the subset of CSS2 supported by XXE, **as well
>   as advanced "proprietary extensions"** needed to style complex XML
>   documents.

http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor//_distrib/doc/csssupport/index.html

Comment: jQuery's [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) is one option if you *need* this in a browser.

Comment: sizzle has similar selectors: http://saucelabs.com/downloads/documentation/css-selector-quickreference.pdf