# When hovering a CSS list item, change the parent items CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple UL list, when you hover over the `More` list item in the HTML below, it unhides it's child menu and shows it.

What I need to do is change the CSS of the actual `More`'s CSS once the child menu is show and hovered.

So if you hover over `More` a child menu becomes visible, you then hover over that child menu.  At this point I need to change the CSS of the Parent of this child menu which would be the menu that has `More` as it's text.

If you know how to do this without Javascript, I would love to know.. Maybe it is not even possible without JS?

```
 <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>

            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>

            <li><a href="">More</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#nav-wrapper ul {
    position:relative;
    width: 700px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav-wrapper ul li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav-wrapper ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#nav-wrapper ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4caef2;
}
#nav-wrapper ul li a:visited {
    color: #666;
}

/* Hide Sub-menus */
#nav-wrapper ul ul{
    display: none;
}
/* SHOW Sub-menus on HOVER */
#nav-wrapper ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    margin:-10px 0 0 0;
    padding:0px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-color:#fff;
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    background:#FFF;
    position:absolute;

    top:45px;
    right: 320px;
    width: 420px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, despite what these other answers say, here's kind of a sneaky way of going about it using the [adjacent selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Link 1</li>
            <li>Sub Link 2</li>
            <li>Sub Link 3</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; }
ul { list-style: none; }
ul > li { position: relative; }
ul li a { 
    height: 16px;
    display: block; }
ul ul { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none; }
ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
ul ul:hover + a { color: red; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/YZtgL/

Answer (score 6):

Old question, and the accepted answer is clever. But this is pretty trivial to achieve, with just a single change in your CSS from:

```
#nav-wrapper ul li a:hover
```

to:

```
#nav-wrapper ul li:hover>a
```

This won't work in IE6 (that browser only understands hover styles on anchors). But then nor does the adjacent sibling combinator selector (+).

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/o5uqujco/) for the fix in action

Comment: This changes the child element, not the parent element

Comment: @JoeLannen - yep, and this achieves exactly what OP asked for. There's no such thing as a parent selector, but by moving the CSS hover styles to the parent `li` like this you don't need one.

Comment: I know there's no parent selector, the question asked to change the parent's CSS. I see where you're going with your solution tho now. cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can not select parent elements in CSS. You'll need javascript/jQuery to accomplish what you want.

[CSS3 selectors...](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to select the parent of an element using CSS. You will have to use JavaScript or JavaScript libraries such as jQuery to implement this.

This might help you.
[Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @CherryFlavourPez above works. The reason why it works is not explained clearly though. Note that the *li* element (the one with the "More" text) is a **parent** of the submenu (the *ul* with the five *li* elements in it). The *a* element is a (adjacent) **sibling** of the submenu. So when you are hovering over the submenu you are actually still hovering over the parent *li* element as well.

Comment: It is still not possible though using only CSS to change the CSS of the parent from the child.

Answer (score -1):

You look here [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and I send an example for you have a nice day

```css
.triggerDiv{
  display:none;
}
.child:hover ~.triggerDiv {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="triggerDiv">
      <p>I'm Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```