# Parent menu item changes background when child is hovered on

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, html-lists, frontend

I'm working on a WordPress site, and when I build a two layer deep menu the parent element highlights the default blue color when a child element is being hovered on. What can I do to change the background of the parent element during this?

[See this image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaJMV.png)
[image: menu image]

```
#access .dropdown-menu li:hover > .sub-menu { visibility: visible; } 
#access .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu { display: block; } 
#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu { background: rgba(25,25,25,0.8); } 
#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu { left: 100%; top: 0; border-top: none; background: rgba(25,25,25,0.8); } 
#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu li a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; } 
#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu li a:hover { color: #7ac143; }`
```

Comment: Show us some of the code that you have been working on?

Comment: I second @Andrew's comment, if possible give us a link to a live demo of the site where this is happening.

Comment: It's unfortunately someone else's code that I have to tidy up, but here's the menu css:
`#access .dropdown-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
#access .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    background: rgba(25,25,25,0.8);
}
#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border-top: none;
    background: rgba(25,25,25,0.8);
}
#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #7ac143;
}`

Comment: @AndrewS. Could you add that code to the main body of your post?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the `li:hover` of the submenu instead of the parent menu (`.dropdown-menu`).

```
#access.dropdown-menu > .sub-menu li:hover { visibility: visible; display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to change the color of the parent WHILE child is being hovered. Unfortunately, there is no ancestor(parent) selector in CSS. If you must achieve this, you would have to use Javascript.

```
$("#access .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu li").hover(function() {
   $(this).parents("#access > .dropdown-menu > li").css('background', 'red');
}, function() {
   $(this).parents("#access > .dropdown-menu > li").css('background', 'blue');
});
```

There is some insanely ingenious way to achieve this using CSS, but I really advise against it. It's dirty. [Change parent when child hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622611/when-hovering-a-css-list-item-change-the-parent-items-css)

Answer (score 0):

A simplified working jQuery solution:

http://jsbin.com/ojikix/1/edit