# How to affect next element of parent element when hover

Tags: css

Html :

```
<div class="first">
   <div class="first-sub">
       <a href="#"></a> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

When I hover on `a` element, need to effect `div` which has class `.second`

Can I do this with only css ? or should I use javascript too ?

Comment: You cannot go up the DOM if you want to affect the next element only on hovering anchor.

Comment: use javascript simply

Comment: You can do this with JQuery.

Comment: This can't be done with CSS for the reason stated by Manoj. Maioman's answer is the closest you are going to be able to get using your existing markup.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622611/when-hovering-a-css-list-item-change-the-parent-items-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [general sibling selector:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```css
div:hover ~ div.second{background:yellow}
```

```html
<div class="first">
   <div class="first-sub">
       <a href="#">first</a> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="second">sec</div>
```

Comment: Anchor number depends on me, I will use 3 anchor element inside of first-sub div. So this way does not work for my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution proposed in another forum & in another post here.

```css
.parent-hover-block {
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 15px;
}

.parent-hover-block > span {
    pointer-events: auto;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 50%;
}

.parent-hover-block:hover ~ .element-to-border-at-span-hover{
    border: 1px dashed red;
}

.element-to-border-at-span-hover{
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-hover-block">
<span>Hovered child (icon)</span> 
</div>
<div class="element-to-border-at-span-hover"> Block to be border at span hover</div>
```

But be careful with pointer-events.

More info here : [How to style the parent element when hovering a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)