# CSS for checkbox's associated label

Tags: css

What's the CSS to make a label of a checked checkbox have a certain style?

This is basically what I want, except I want the label to have the background: blue, not the checkbox.

```
.results .auto-share-options li label input[type='checkbox']:checked {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ascend with CSS selectors at this current time and checkbox `input` elements are *empty* elements, so you can't look for a descendent `label` element either.

You would need to use JavaScript to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of doing this in CSS. Exhaustive answers and solutions available here: [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)