# Changing elements CSS properties based on child element

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

This is my markup:

```
<ol class="wp-paginate">
    <li><span class="title"></span></li>
    <li><span class="page current">1</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/page/2/" title="2" class="page">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/page/2/" class="next">»</a></li>
</ol>
```

And I want to change the `background-position` property of the `li` element that has a `span` child with the class `current`. In this case, the second list item.

I do consider myself proficient with CSS, but I really cannot think of how to do that. Maybe there isn't a way, or I'm just having a brain fart.

Thanks!

Comment: this is not achievable using css.Use jquery to do this.

Comment: At least not yet, soon (hopefully :) you'll be able to do this: `ul li! span.current {properties here will style the li, not the span}`. I was pretty sure it was `$li`, not `li!` (Paul Irish wrote about it on G+) but according to this it's not: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject. You could also try this jQuery plugin: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/01/use-css4-parent-selector-right-now-with-cssparentselector-js/

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do this in CSS. You'll have to resort to Javascript for that.

If you really want to do this in pure CSS, you'll have to move the `current` class onto the `li`s themselves.

---

**Side note:** In [CSS**4**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) you'll be able to do the following:

```
.wp-paginate $li span.current { }
```

Needless to say, not a single browser currently supports this.

Comment: Argh, that's a pain. The wordpress plugin I'm using outputs its markup as that, which is a pain in the ass. Thanks though!

Comment: @MartinHoe - You can modify it using Javascript. Interested?

Comment: It's alright, I changed my CSS ruling to apply a lot of the properties to the `a` tags instead of `li`, and it works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not currently possible with CSS.  See: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

You will need to either edit the html output, or perform the selection via JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Its nearly impossible with javascript.

Using jQuery

```
$("li").each(function() {
  if($(this).find("span.current").length > 0) {
    $(this).css("backgroundPostion", "top left");  
  }
});
```