# remove link underline from image only if the anchor tag contains an img

Tags: jquery, css, image, hyperlink, border

```
<a href="#">
        <img width="103" height="100"  src="img source">
    </a>
```

for the above html code I am using the following css

```
a {
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

a img {
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve here to underline the text links while keeping img links without any underline. however I guess by styling the text links I am also styling image links, I want any image in a link should not be underlined.

Can any one suggest work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underline is caused by the text decoration on the a. So just apply `text-decoration:none` to the a.

**Edit**: there is currently no CSS-only way to apply a style to "any `a` that has an `img` as its child". CSS does not have selectors for that. So you'll either have to make these `a`s unique by giving them classes (or other attributes) and apply the CSS to those classes, or run some script that tests for `img`s in `a`s and gives those `a`s the desired style.

Comment: this will remove underline for text links also, I want to remove it only for image links, I mean if the anchor tag contains image only and not the text

Comment: Well, you can, for instance, give all `a`s that contain images a certain class and use the `text-decoration:none` only for that class.

Comment: this solution works if the contents (links) are static, in my case these links are added to site by end user using CMS, I have no control to add class to such links with css only I might have to use jquery here. Isn't it possible with css only?

Comment: No, not without handles like class names and such. You will need javascript then. Or something server side, if adding the stuff causes a page load.

Comment: is there something available in css3  with pattern matching and attribute selector ? with the help of this I may be able to select such anchor tags and remove the underline from these tags?

Comment: yep, not getting any way to do it with CSS only approach, using jquery  for this particular problem
 $("a img").parent().css('border','0px');

Answer (score 10):

After a lot of Googling I finally found a neat trick that worked for me:

```
a img { border:none; vertical-align:top; }
```

> **Why this works?**
>
> By default both anchors and images are inline elements and by applying
>   vertical-align:top; to an image inside an anchor, we move the anchor
>   to the top of the image. For some reason images have higher z-index
>   than anchors.

Source: [Remove Border from Image Links](http://konstruktors.com/blog/web-design/1122-remove-border-from-image-links)

By the way, it would work great with a parent selector like `a < img` ... unfortunately this isn't implemented yet, but is in the workings. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530/114029

Comment: Simple and functional. Really helpful. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS Descendent Selector](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200510/css_21_selectors_part_2/)

So, in your case:

```
a > img { text-decoration: none; }
```

However, the above rule will add the style to the image (that is the descendent) and not the parent, so it might not be what you're looking for. Unfortunately, there is no CSS rule that applies styling to the parent in case of a descendent.

Comment: Exactly. Giving a child `text-decoration:none` will do nothing for the decoration of the parent. That is, the line will still be drawn. And you're right that CSS does not have any rules for "an element that is the parent of another element". Maybe in CSS4.

Comment: @MrLister: CSS4 does seem to have proposed an ascendant selector (http://davidwalsh.name/css4-preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set a class for each link that has an image inside of it, you prolly must use javascript. You could simply add something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var a_with_img = $('a').children()
    $(a_with_img).parent().css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

This should work, however it's never a good idea to target all the 'a' selectors with js, it's pretty heavy on the load. Might cause slowdowns to your overall pageload.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this using jquery just link the jquery.js in the head and put this in the body:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("body").ready(function () {

                $("a").has("img").addClass("imglink");

        });
</script>
```

Then style the class a.imglink