# How to combine the ::after and :not pseudo selectors

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SASS code:

```
section.post {
  a {
    transition: all $aside-animation-time;

    &::after {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -.5px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      content: '';
      border-bottom: 1px solid $primary-color;
    }
    &:hover {
      border-color: $hover-color;
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm doing here is adding a blue bottom border for all links. However, I noticed that when I use anchor tags with images inside, the image also has the border (since it's a link as well). Now, my goal is to append the anchor styles to text links only.

What I tried so far is using `:not(img)`, chaining it with `::after`, overriding the previous rules etc., but nothing worked as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's gonna be hard(ish) after all you're styling the link, not the image. You may need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Its `&:after`, not `&::after`

Comment: @Brewal: It's either. In fact, [the latter is now preferred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684797/should-i-use-single-colons-or-double-colons-for-before-after-first-le/28527928#28527928).

Comment: @BoltClock Ok nevermind... Why is the latter better ? (ok thanks for the link)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060763/remove-link-underline-from-image-only-if-the-anchor-tag-contains-an-img

Comment: @Paulie_D: The underline here is created using a pseudo-element, not a bottom border or a text decoration.

Comment: You'll have either to add a class to the `a` elements containing `img`, or add a `span` into the `a` elements that does not.

Comment: True but I think the principal is the same....it's almost a **parent selector** issue.

Comment: it could be useful to see an example of the style created with the link, maybe it is possible to play with some css applied to the image and hide that style

Comment: There could be indeed [a way](http://jsfiddle.net/axtny7pw/) to hide the border, but it makes the code quite ugly IMO.

Comment: or apply a `box-shadow: 1px 0 0 1px #fff;` to the image instead of negative margin-bottom

Comment: Yes. It seems you want to target the pseudo selector of a parent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently CSS doesn't have an option to style the parent based on any child elements. If you were styling the image itself with the link it would be fine.

You might be able to use something like jQuery to add a class to any links which contain child images:

```
$('a:has(img)').addClass('has_img');
```

You can then use this with your CSS :not as in

```
section.post {
  a:not(.has_img) {
    transition: all $aside-animation-time;

    &::after {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -.5px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      content: '';
      border-bottom: 1px solid $primary-color;
    }

    &:hover {
      border-color: $hover-color;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

```
a {
  display: block;
  height: 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  &:after {
    border-bottom: thin solid blue;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: red;
  }
  img {
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Quick Codepen sample:
http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/WvMGRK