# Change list-style-type if it has a hyperlink - without javascript/jQuery

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

I have the following code:

```
<li>
  <a href="jsfiddle.net">Text</a>
</li>
<li>
  only text
</li>​
```

I have applied css to li element as:

```
li {list-style-type: circle;}
```

I want that the element li on hover should have **list-style-type:disc**, but **only if** it has an **anchor element** inside it. I know its a cakewalk using javascript, but is it possible to achieve this without javascript?

I have tried something like this, but could not achieve it: http://jsfiddle.net/k5SQe/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "parent" selector in CSS. You cannot add a circle style to a `<li>` element, with the given requirements.

Though, it's possible to add the bullet to the anchor **: http://jsfiddle.net/k5SQe/31/**

```
li:hover a {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Comment: thanks Rob for replying. But the extra margin-left causes two bullets to appear which does not look good.

Comment: @Ankit The margin was just an example. Adjust it to fit your needs.

Comment: I tried changing margin values, but if I give 0em , it does not display at all. Seems like it's not possible using CSS alone :(  .. anyways +1 for your efforts.

Comment: Check this screenshot http://i46.tinypic.com/5nngub.png . I am able to see 2 bullets on hover.

Comment: @Ankit I've updated my answer. Your original demo didn't contain a `<ul>` or `<ol>`. I've added it, and the solution works, without having to modify the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your circumstances, add a class to `<li>` elements that contain links.

http://jsfiddle.net/k5SQe/10/

Comment: if I were to have a class selector, I would not have posted this query probably :) .. anyways thanks for your reply.

Comment: No problem, best to check. Glad you found the solution!