# CSS - design parent class if child has a specific class

Tags: html, css, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Is there a way to design parent class based on if its child elements has a specific class?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content1">
      text
   </div>
</div>
```

.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content2">
      text
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to design the first `.container` differently based on if the child class is `content1` or `content2`.
It must be pure css solution, without javascript.

Answer (score 11):

2012 answer:

> No, you can't do that.  CSS can't select elements based on their
> children, except to check whether or not the element is empty.

2022 answer: the `:has()` selector, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

e.g. `.container:has(> .content1)` will select elements classed as `.container` which are the direct parent of an element classed as `.content1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't supported on Firefox yet.

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking for is the the mythical CSS parent selector. Perhaps some day.

Comment: 10 years later it's here, `has()`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `container1` + `content` and `container2` + `content`?

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="content">
      text
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
    <div class="content">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

And then write CSS like so:

```
.container1 .content {
    /* Container 1 styles here */
}

.container2 .content {
    /* Container 2 styles here */
}
```

Comment: Won't those apply the styles to the .content elements? Just to clarify, I thought his requirement was to apply styles to the container elements and not the children.

Comment: @Asad: Yes, if there is other content outside of the `.content` div, but inside a `.container` div that needs to be styled, then the OP can simply write rules for `.container1` and `.container2`