# How to set a style one a parent element

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

How can I set the style of my `<li>` based in a class of a child element?

example:

```
<div class"options">
<ul>
   <li> <a href="#"> option 1 </a> </li>
   <li> <a href="#"> option 2 </a> </li>
   <li> <a class="last" href="#"> option 3 </a> </li>

   <li> <a href="#"> option 4 </a> </li>
   <li> <a href="#"> option 5 </a> </li>
   <li> <a class="last" href="#"> option 6 </a> </li>

   <li> <a href="#"> option 7 </a> </li>
   <li> <a href="#"> option 8 </a> </li>
   <li> <a class="last" href="#"> option 9 </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I can style the `a` with `.options li a.last { ... }`

but what I want is to apply `margin:0` to the parent `li`, and I have no way to control what's inside `<li>`, only what's inside `<a>`.

> Is there any style trick?

---

What I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

I have a jQuery loop to add the `.last` class to every 3rd `<li>` as

```
$(".box-left li").each(function (i) {
    if ((i+1) % 3 == 0) 
        $(this).addClass("last");
});
```

But I wanted to learn if there's other way that does not involve a javascript helper.

Comment: Do you want to apply `margin:0` to parent `li` of `a` with class last?

Comment: @Robbie though it can have the same answer, the question is very different and might help other reach here where they are not searching for "complex css selectors" but a more used "set a style on a parent element" ... for such, and agreeing with [Joel Spolsky](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4) on this kind of questions, it should not be closed.

Comment: But surely that's semantics? A bit of googling would sort it out? http://www.google.com/m?q=set+a+style+on+a+parent+element (which is exactly your quote)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with CSS sadly, best I can offer you is jQuery and it's [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) selector.

Alternatively, make all your margins/paddings on the `a` tag instead of the `li` tag. This will involve some shuffling but will achieve what you need

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to select a parent element in CSS.

This question has been asked multiple times and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child/45530#45530) seems to sum it up quite well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to select parent element of a child element.
May be this will helpful to u
Specify the 
    li{line-height:20px;}
    li a{display:block;}