# Changing background-color of parent element on hover

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, background-color

Below is my html code.

```
        <div class="container">
            <a class="link1" href="">Link1</a>
            <a class="link2" href="">Link2</a>
            <a class="link3" href="">Link3</a>              
        </div>
```

Is there any selectors in CSS that when I hover mouse on Link1 or Link2, the `background-color` of `container` gets change. Since I am new & self thought that's why I have some problems.

Comment: Are you changing the background on hover over SOME links or ALL links?

Comment: some link... for example... if i hover on Link1 i want the background-color of 'container' to be #e5e5e5  & when i hover on Link2 , background-color should change to #1e1e1e , same goes on.

Comment: You'd need javascript to accomplish this. CSS doesn't let you reference parent elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change parent div to a different background when hovering over individual child divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555255/change-parent-div-to-a-different-background-when-hovering-over-individual-child)

Comment: i am new... i spent all my day on using jquery for this effect... but every time i fail.... well... i'll continue.. thanks all

Answer (score 2):

CSS4 (yup) introduces the `:has()` psuedo-class ( http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational ) however this not currently supported by any current (as of September 2014) engine or browser.

If it was supported, then the (currently proposed) syntax would be:

```
div.container:has(a.link1:hover) { background-image("link1.png"); }
div.container:has(a.link2:hover) { background-image("link2.png"); }
div.container:has(a.link3:hover) { background-image("link3.png"); }
```

Until then, you'll need to rely on Javascript, such as jQuery's similar `has` ( http://api.jquery.com/has/ ).

Answer (score 1):

The Short Answer is **No**. There is no way to select parents or in ascending order.

The best you can do is change the HTML and use another element to fake the background of the parent.

Like this:

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
        <a class="link1" href="">Link1</a>
        <a class="link2" href="">Link2</a>
        <a class="link3" href="">Link3</a> 
        <div class="fake"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.fake {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
.link1, .link2, .link3 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
.link1:hover ~ .fake {
    background:#CCC;
}
.link2:hover ~ .fake {
    background:brown;
}
.link3:hover ~ .fake {
    background:orange;
}
```

Check This Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/g7brnb9q/**

About the `~` selector helps to select sibling elements, in this case any element with `fake` class after the links.

Chek Here more about this [GO HERE](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/general)

Comment: BTW whats the use of ~ ??

Comment: Glad to help you mate . If you need any explanation about the code let me know. @Gull check the edit

Comment: @Gull, the `~` is a general sibiling selector... It targets the elements that comes after the selected one, and are on the same node level... In this case `.fake` is a sibiling to `.link1` and comes after it.

Comment: what @LcSalazar, also worth noting is its the same as `+` but less strict. The sibling selector `+` selects the first proceeding sibling. `~` selects all proceeding siblings

Comment: @Gull if your question is solved don't forget to mark it as finished.

Comment: @Danko where is the option for marking as Finished... ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no parent selector on css...

If it's ok for you to have a javascript approach, you could do something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("link1")[0].onmouseover = function() {
    this.parentNode.backgroundColor = "red";
};
document.getElementsByClassName("link2")[0].onmouseover = function() {
    this.parentNode.backgroundColor = "green";
};
document.getElementsByClassName("link3")[0].onmouseover = function() {
    this.parentNode.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
```