# Select parent n layers up in the tree using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an app with relatively complex DOM structure with 20+ layers of divs.

If I have a div with `class="active"` somewhere in the middle of the tree, how can I select it's parent **n** layers up in the tree using CSS?

For example, how do I select the div marked in uppercase (4 layers up) in the following tree ? :

```
<DIV>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="active">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</DIV>
```

Same considering first-child ? How to select a first-child **n** layers down the tree ?

Comment: What do you mean by a first child n layers down the tree?

Comment: What I mean is "first-child of first-child of first-child" would be a "first child 3 layers down the tree".

Comment: In that case there's no shortcut, you'll need to do `:first-child > :first-child > :first-child`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this article I found titling [CSS4 Preview](http://davidwalsh.name/css4-preview), it will be possible in CSS4 to style parent elements. The article shows that it would be possible to style parent elements like the following:

```
$div > div > div > div.active { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

(Given example would style the `div` nested 3 layers up in the tree related to `div.active`)

Going back to my app, using PHP and inline CSS, I would be able to control the **n** (nesting depth).

Until CSS4 though, I will use some kind of jQuery solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [there is no such thing as a parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child). You'll have to set a class on the desired element directly, either by hand, or with some server-side code, or via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The latest browser versions have recently started to support ":has()" CSS selector (see the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/css-has)).

So, in your case the CSS would be:

```css
div:has(div > div > div > div.active){
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<DIV>
Some content
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="active">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</DIV>
```