# CSS style for parent instead of child?

Tags: css

I am using jquery to insert html I get from the server into a div. Based on the div contents i'd like to adjust the syle of the container. I wrote up a simple html test. How do I tell css to apply this site when it has X child? After googling I tried :has and :contains with neither working. I don't want to keep my styles in JS as css makes more sense.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wd9fk/

html

```
<div id="a"><div id="b">B</div></div>
<div id="a"><div id="c">C</div></div>
```

css

```
#a { height: 400px; border: 1px solid red;  }
#b { height: 200px; }
#a :has #b { height: 300px; border: 1px solid blue; }
```

Comment: Using jQuery it's easy. I'm not sure it can be done in pure CSS.

Comment: 1) Not possible in CSS 2) Why do you have two `#a` in the same HTML?

Comment: Interesting! A definite +1. I shall try, though not sure...

Comment: @BoltClock: Oops, good catch! I guess that should be a class but in my real code its an id and b/c is inserted in

Comment: You better not use same ids for different elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: which itself is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child ...

Comment: @Alex Feinman: I'm still contemplating merging the two questions since their code and answers are so similar, but there's so much going on that I think I'll be keeping them separate for a while...

Comment: @user1955298 I think you should have picked Alec’s answer. The one you picked contains misleading information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply cannot traverse up the DOM in CSS. You will need to use JavaScript.

Here is an article explaining why: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors

Long story short, it's due to the way CSS is read by the browser, and by introducing it, it would increase the performance hit by a factor of ten (at least!), because it would need to read every single node multiple times to see whether or not it fits the profile.

It's a nice thought, but it's simply not viable.

Answer (score 4):

There is no parent selector for CSS yet, there are plans and it is being discussed though. In CSS Selectors level 4, a [subject selector has been proposed](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject), which would let you refer to elements this way:

```
ol! > li:only-child
```

Which then reads: “an `ol` element that contains a single `li` element” (this syntax is a proposal though), and would let you style the parent `ol` element.

If this proposal succeeds, subject selectors would be available in the next version of CSS selectors.

For now, Javascript is the way to go, until the subject selector becomes a standard.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot traverse up the DOM to get the parent selector of current matching elements.

But you can do it with jQuery quite easy like this:

```
$('#Default a span.active').closest('.vehicle_details').css('background-color','#444');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MZ9wa/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
#a > #b { height: 300px; border: 1px solid blue; }
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but give it a try.

Regards.

Comment: This will style `#b`if it is the immediate child of `#a`. I think this is the opposite what OP seeks.