# Kendo TreeView selected CSS inside div

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I had this kendo treeview. When select a `node` or `sub's-node` I want the orange color at full line and same with others (refer to image below).

I to use script below, but when it come to sub's-group the align is not same. Appreciate your help.

```
.k-treeview span.k-in {
  margin-left: -10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 60%;  
}
```

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/erADeDiq)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicated or similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509590/selecting-an-element-that-has-a-specific-child

Answer (score 0):

The way the tree currently works is that the `li.k-item` have a left padding of 16px, so for the second level it's 32px and so on.

What you need to do is put the indenting mechanism somewhere else. Your `li.k-item` must have no left padding, but a div inside must. Depending on your item template, it will be something like:

```
.k-treeview li > div { padding-left: 16px }
.k-treeview li li > div { padding-left: 32px }
.k-treeview li li li > div { padding-left: 48px }
```

You can generate a dozen levels with less or sass.

When you have this, you can style the selected row:

```
li[aria-selected="true"] { border: 2px solid orange }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make selected margin same as all? means if I select sub-child padding or margin line same as parents