# Form li background change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, focus

I'm trying to achieve the effect of the li tag changing background colors when the user focuses on the input (effect can be seen at the bottom of the page [here](http://secondandpark.com/). From seeing similar questions it seems like it can't be done in pure CSS, so I was wondering how to do it in jquery (I have no knowledge). Here is my HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="" method="post" name="contact-form">  
        <ul>   
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" class="test"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <textarea name="message" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child

Comment: @vytfla take a look at my answer, includes the fading effect from the example given.

Comment: @AbstractChaos I believe I am missing something then. I have <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> in my <head> tag followed by your code within <script type="text/javascript"></script and it's not working.

Comment: @vytfla you are missing [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/) required to allow background to fade

Comment: @AbstractChaos How do I add that?

Comment: @vytfla visit the site and download add a script tag

Comment: So, essentially what I posted above, but instead between the script tag add http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js?

Comment: not instead, as well as you need both, Jquery UI is a extension of Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it. It will add a background color to the parent LI of the form field that has focus, and after exiting the field the background color will be removed.

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/v9BAE/).

CSS:

```
.selected {
    background: lightYellow;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var $form = $(".contact-form"),
        selectedClass = "selected";

    $form.on("focus", "input, textarea", function () {
        $(this).closest("li")
            .addClass(selectedClass);
    });

    $form.on("blur", "input, textarea", function () {
        $(this).closest("li")
            .removeClass(selectedClass);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :hover selector in your CSS statement; no need for JS at all..

```
.contact-form ul li { background-color:#000000; }
.contact-form ul li:hover { background-color: #C0C0C0; }
```

Comment: This isn't supported in IE 6 & 7.

Comment: Man I wasn't thinking, this is useful and good alternative. Thanks.

Comment: @htmled yeah... you're likely right. I stopped supporting IE6 and IE7 about 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a basic jquery version which activates on focus like example

```
$('.contact-form').on('focus','input,textarea',function() {
    $('.contact-form li').animate({'backgroundColor':'#00FF00'});

    $(this).parent().animate({'backgroundColor':'#FF0000'});
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvtkT/)