# CSS apply border to <li> if it has an <a> tag inside

Tags: css

I have something like this:

```
<li> 
    <a href="http://google.pt">google</a>
</li>
<li>
    <h3>Hello World</h3 
</li>
```

and I'd like to apply a border to all `<li>` that have an `<a>` inside. But I can't use an `id` because this code needs to work for any page and I can't control the ids. Is this possible via CSS?

edit:
ok lets give some context. i am making a firefox plugin that would change the mouse when you move over a link. the problem is that on some pages like google if i add the css to the `<a>` tag it wont work on some of the links

Comment: Yes, with CSS classes...

Comment: @Bojangles - no, it's not. There's no "parent" seletor (yet) in CSS. OP would need to use JavaScript.

Comment: You say you can't use IDs, but can you use classes? Or are you looking to just use CSS without modifying the HTML at all?

Comment: I believe this question has been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible purely with CSS if you can't edit HTML.  It involves going down the cascade, to the `a`, then back up to style the `li`, which CSS can't do (yet). You'll need to use javascript/jquery to get that "going up" functionality.

Or alternatively, make the `a` 100% width and height of the `li`, and then just apply the border to the `a`

Comment: If you want to use jQuery: `$("li:has(a)")` or to select by text content `$("li:contains('blah')")`

Comment: In general, you are right but your second sentence can be misleading because CSS selectors are evaluated from right to left, i.e. going up the cascade.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
li > a {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

**Update:**
CSS selectors are evaluated from right to left. So, when the browser is looking for `li` it does not look at it's children but look at it's parent. [Why we don't have a parent selector](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors).

Comment: Not what OP wants. He only wants the border if `li` has a child `a`, he can't put a class on it.

Comment: I don't see any class there, and that does look like it only borders `li` if it has a child `a`...

Comment: Andy, there is no class here. Someone edited my answer with a wrong link.

Comment: @bancer Ah ok. Well you are putting the border on the `a` here, not the `li`. `li > a` converts to "all `a` tags with an `li` parent`

Comment: @Andy, that's right. But the effect is the same as if you put the border on `li`.

Comment: @bancer That's not what OP asked, he wants the border on the li. The effect is only the same in this case, it may be different in OP's case

Answer (score 0):

In it's own / your own CSS class:

```
.hasLink{
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Reference the class on your html (assuming we call this main.css):

```
<link href="/Content/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then whenever you have a `<li>` with `<a>`:

```
<li class="hasLink">

  <a href="http://google.pt">Google</a>

</li>
```

Does that help? I'm not sure if you wanted something smarter than that maybe...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
.someClass{ border: 1px solid #anycolor;}
```

And your html

```
<li class="someClass">
   <a href="#">Something</a>
</li>

<li>
   <h3>other</h3>
</li>
```