# css selector to select a table cell contains img

Tags: css, selector

I would like to make font color of a table cell where there is a img inside it red. How would I use css selector to specifically do that? The question can be extend to how to select an element which has a specific type of element as its children. Thanks

Comment: You need javascript to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/45004/2129835

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select all `td` containing `img` in CSS:

```css
td:has(img)
```

To select all `td` having a direct child `img` in CSS:

```css
td:has(> img)
```

---

<strike>[In CSS4 there is a spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject), to mark the element, which you want to style, in a larger selector. The actual symbol varies and currently points to `!`.</strike>

So in your case the selector would look like this (according to the current spec):

```
table !td img {
  font-color: red;
}
```

Note, however, that this is not supported in any current browser.

Comment: Can I ask why you bothered even putting an answer like this when it is "not supported in any current browser"? That is effectively equivalent to not being an answer at all.

Comment: Just to point out further developments. I do not expect this answer to be accepted, but add this for reference later on.

Comment: I like answers that contain what may be coming, but it does seem like such an answer should also include a solution for the here and now (since obviously the OP needs some answer for today, not whenever CSS4 may come about in browsers).

Answer (score 3):

Do you know ahead of time which cells will have an image in them?  If so add a class to the td element, for example:

```
<tr>
   <td class="has-image"><img src="..." /></td>
</tr>
```

That's the easiest way... Otherwise you'd need to use JavaScript.  In jquery this would look like:

```
$('td img').parents('td').addClass('has-image');
```