# CSS highlight a parent element when a child is highlighted

Tags: css

Is there a CSS only method of highlighting a parent menu item when I child, or grandchild is hovered.

EG.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="link">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link">Item 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">Item 1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="link">Item 1.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So in the example above can I target "Item 1" with a style when "Item 1.1", "Item 1.2" or "Item 1.3" are hovered over?

Thanks.

Comment: It does not appear so. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child

Comment: FWIW CSS Selectors Level 4 will include a subject selector which allows you to change _which_ element in the selector gets styled, so you could do `li! > a {this will style any li that has an a as a direct child}`. Edit: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can apply :hover to the elements... hovering a child will also imply the mouse being 'over' the parent.

In the simple case given.

```
li:hover{font-weight: bold;}
```

Now you want to restrict the child elements not being hovered over

```
li:hover li{font-weight: normal}
```

Now you need to re-highlight hovered children.

```
li:hover li:hover{font-weight: bold;}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPsycho/wppzk/)

Comment: Nice one. So simple when someone tells you the answer :)  Thanks for your help.