# CSS change style if nested element

Tags: css

Is there a way in CSS to adjust the style of a parent element, if a nested element exists?

For example, let's say we have a button with padding on the right and left of 10px.

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

Now, let's say we add an icon to this:

```
<button><i class="icon"></i> Submit</button>
```

Due to the icon, the spacing on the left of the button is too wide.  Is there a way without adding an additional class to the button, to say if it contains `<i>`, make the padding less on the left?

Thanks!

Comment: CSS does not have a "parent" selector so you'll have to do something else

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: as other have said, not yet. You could use negative margin on the `<i/>` however which would replicate this, particular, effect

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45530/248129) goes into detail about why there are no parent selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, You cannot do this at the moment. It is proposed for [css4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should just use a different element to target. This is where elements which are void of semantic meaning like `<span>` come in handy:

```
<button><span class="text">Submit</span></button>
<button><i class="icon"></i> <span class="text">Submit</span></button>
```

If you use that HTML, you could just target `.text` with the `margin`/`padding` instead.