# Selector to combine Asterisk and parent element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know that the Asterisk match all items inside an element. Is there any selector, that includes the parent element too?

**Sample HTML**

```
<p>
    foobar
    <span>
        foobar
    </span>
</p>
```

**Sample CSS**

```
p * {
    background-color:aqua;
}
```

Now only the span elements inside the p gets the background-color. Is there a selector which matches the p tag and all tags inside the p tag? Or do i still have to use

```
p, p * {
    background-color:aqua;
}
```

**NOTE** The `background-color` is only dummy content.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but why not use simply the 'p' selector ?

Comment: I think the `background-color` is somehwat confusing. It's only a dummy attribute to point out the problem.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad :-) So I think you'll have to stick with the 'p, p *' selector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any selector, that includes the parent element too?

**No.** See [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) for a more detailed explanation.

It has been suggested with css level 4, and rejected : [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child/45530#45530)

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use `p, p *`, although depending on the property you're applying, if it is inherited by default it should be enough to simply apply it to `p` and have its descendants inherit it instead. If you explicitly apply it to all the descendants, you may break inheritance chains unnecessarily.

Considering the nature of a background, I don't see much of a point in applying a background color to all of the descendants of `p` along with the `p` itself.