# Apply style to parent if it has child with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply `styles` to the `parent` if it has `child` elements.

So far, I've applied styles to the `child` elements if present. But I want to `style` the `parent` if the `parent` has `child`, using ONLY `CSS`.

following is the `html`

```
<ul class="main">
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>bbbb</li>
            <li>bbbb
                <ul>
                    <li>cccc</li>
                    <li>cccc</li>
                    <li>cccc</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>bbbb</li>
            <li>bbbb</li>
            <li>bbbb</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
</ul>
```

the `css` code

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.main li {
    display:inline-block;
    background:yellow;
    color:green;
}
.main > li > ul > li {
    background:orange
}
.main > li > ul > li > ul >li {
    background:pink;
}
```

working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/TDV54/)

Comment: You can't. Bash the spec makers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: It's not possible, use the jquery.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only answer this question in a comment, but there is a CSS Selector for :empty so If you style the element for with children and then style for when no children with :empty you should achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use `has()`:

```css
ul li:has(ul.sub) { ... }
```

---

<strike>It's not possible with CSS3. There is a proposed CSS4 selector, `$`, to do just that, which could look like this (Selecting the `li` element):</strike>

```
ul $li ul.sub { ... }
```

See the [list of CSS4 Selectors here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/).

As an alternative, with jQuery, a one-liner you could make use of would be this:

```
$('ul li:has(ul.sub)').addClass('has_sub');
```

You could then go ahead and style the `li.has_sub` in your CSS.

Comment: According to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector the :has() pseudoclass no longer works with any browser as of 2016. Just so people don't get frustrated at this not working.

Comment: any developments ?

Comment: :has() should be the proposed CSS4 selector instead of the more obscure $ one ...

Comment: `$` now replaced with `!` appended to a selector. Look here for more info: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu you are right, w3 is so backwards

Comment: According to the Feb 2018 working draft, `!` has been replaced with `:has()`

Comment: As of 2/10/2022 :has is not supported by firefox or chrome. But MANY css4 selectors are!
Using https://css4-selectors.com/browser-selector-test/ as a reference.

Comment: 2022 :has() if finally implemented by Chrome (desktop) version 105, by Safari (both on mobile and desktop). I guess in about 6 months to 1 year we will finally have a stable :has() and solved this problem forever.

Comment: today I tried to use the :has() pseudoClass and it worked as expected to apply style to a parent with a child having certain class.
Chrome version used: 109.0.5414.120
MS Edge version used: 109.0.1518.70