# How to apply style only to the parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have such HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-transform: uppercase;">
      Some text node.
      <span>Some text in span</span>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I write style for TD element, that will not affect child SPAN element? In my case SPAN must stay in normal text transform.

Note that I can modify the style only for the TD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply style to parent if it has child with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252551/apply-style-to-parent-if-it-has-child-with-css)

Comment: You can't do this.  CSS cascades downward.  You would need to modify the child `<span>`'s style to override anything you did in its parent `<td>`, or put the styling that you don't want to cascade in a sibling element instead of a parent (`<td><span style="text-transform:uppercase">styled text</span><span>unstyled text</span></td>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style for the span is `text-transform: inherit`.

There is no way to change the style of its parent without it inheriting other than to explicitly set it to a different value.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
td span {
    text-transform:none;
}
```

Inline CSS:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-transform: uppercase;">
      Some text node.
      <span style="text-transform: none;">Some text in span</span>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("td span").css("text-transform", "none");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if I could do so, I would not have asked you.

Comment: In regards to pure CSS here's an interesting page about parent selectors in CSS: https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/ - it was thought about a few years back but was never put in place due to performance concerns etc. I can't think of a CSS way of achieving what you require.