# Apply style to :host if child contains class (with pure css or typescript)

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

Here's my .html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="content-wrapper" [ngClass]='{"isLoggedIn" : isLoggedIn}'>
  <div class="content-wrapper-body">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

My .css (summed up):

```
:host {     
  ...
  .content-wrapper {
    ...
    .content-wrapper-body {
      ...
    } 
  }
}

.isLoggedIn {     
  &.content-wrapper {
    ...
  }
  .content-wrapper-body {
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to add a style to *app-root* (:host) when the child element has the class *isLoggedIn*

I tried:

```
:host(.isLoggedIn) {
..
}
```

and

```
app-root:has(div.isLoggedIn) {
...
}
```

But still, no success. Can someone help me?

Comment: The `:has()` pseudo-selector has no support in any browser yet. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252551/apply-style-to-parent-if-it-has-child-with-css
Check the link.