# Use CSS :not() to target selected content in an element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a `.header` div with a span `maindomain` and a div `otherdomains` inside of it:

```
<div class="header"><span class="maindomain">LatestFooty.co.uk</span> is currently available for sale, along with:
<div class="otherdomains">    
LatestFootie.com<br>
LatestFootie.co.uk
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target the *is currently available for sale, along with:*, without touching the contents of `.maindomain` or `.otherdomains`. I understand that the best approach to this might be to wrap it in a span and target that instead, but at this point I'd like to figure out why I can't get the `:not` pseudo-class working.

Here is what I have:

```
@media (min-width:300px) and (max-width:450px) {
  .header:not(.maindomain):not(.otherdomains) {
  font-style: italic;  
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the syntax is correct, and I don't think it's a specificity issue because `!important` doesn't make a difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: header is the parent element of the ones you don't want to target.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49609442/8620333 you will need 2 CSS rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.header:not(.maindomain):not(.otherdomains)` only targets elements which have the `.header` class and don't have the `.maindomain` and/or the `.otherdomain` class themselves.

Your rules currently say:

`<div class="header">` is targeted

`<div class="header maindomain">` is not targeted

`<div class="header otherdomains">` is not targeted

`<div class="header maindomain otherdomains">` is not targeted

But this is not what you want to do here obviously.

You cannot apply rules to the `.header` class depending on classes of its children with CSS alone.

There's an approved answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252551/apply-style-to-parent-if-it-has-child-with-css) which might guide you in the right direction (using JavaScript or jQuery in that case).

Comment: So I've misunderstood how `:not()` works, fair enough. JavaScript or jQuery would be overkill so I think at this point it'd be better to just wrap a span around the text in question. Thank you.

Comment: @Hashim that would be the best approach, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You will need two selectors:

```css
.header {
  font-style:italic;
}
.header .otherdomains,
.header .maindomain {
  font-style:initial;
}

/* OR
.header * {
  font-style:initial;
}

*/
```

```html
<div class="header"><span class="maindomain">LatestFooty.co.uk</span> is currently available for sale, along with:
<div class="otherdomains">    
LatestFootie.com<br>
LatestFootie.co.uk
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I chose the other answer because it is the more direct answer to the question, but I've upvoted for explaining how this can be accomplished in CSS without `:not()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to target the "is currently available for sale, along with:", without touching the contents of `.maindomain` or `.otherdomains`.

You can't target anonymous elements in CSS.

CSS rules need a "hook" in the HTML to attach to. That hook is an HTML tag. Without the tag, CSS has nothing to target. This concept applies across box models.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model):

> An anonymous box is created when there is not an HTML element to use for the box. This situation happens when, for example, you declare `display: flex` on a parent element, and directly inside there is a run of text not contained in another element. In order to fix the box tree, an anonymous box is created around that run of text. It will then behave as a flex item, however, **it cannot be targeted and styled like a regular box because there is no element to target**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Everything is in the demo itself, the JavaScript is for demo purposes.

#### Demo

```js
const lnx = [...document.links];
lnx.forEach(lnk => lnk.addEventListener('click', viewHTML));
function viewHTML(e) {
  const link = e.target;
  const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.'+this.dataset.tag);
  headers.forEach(hdr => {
    if (!hdr.matches('.hide')) {
      link.className = 'off';
      let str = hdr.outerHTML;
      let txt = document.createElement('div');
      txt.className = 'txt';
      hdr.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', txt);
      hdr.nextElementSibling.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', str);
      hdr.classList.add('hide'); 
    } else {
      link.className = '';
      hdr.classList.remove('hide');
      hdr.nextElementSibling.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 2.5vw/1.5 Consolas
}

[class^=header] {
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Header (OP)
Selector fails -- :not() is prefixed incorrectly
.header:...  means .header is targeted
.header :... means the descendants of .header is targeted
There is no .header.A, .header.B, nor .header.A.B 
so .header without .A and/or .B will have everything in italics
*/
.header:not(.A):not(.B) {
  font-style: italic;  
}

/* Header 1
Best solution with no extra HTML tags:
Assign font-style: normal...
directly (.C1, .D1)
or by class (.N)
*/
.header1 {
  font-style: italic;
}

.C1,
.D1,
.N {
  font-style: normal;
}

/* Header 2
Using :not() needs extra HTML tag:
Wrap second textnode in an inline or inline-block tag
As content of a descendant tag, the text can be targeted
*/
.header2 *:not(.E):not(.F) {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Header 3
Smart solution with extra HTML tag:
Wrap second textnode in <i> or <em>
*/
.header3 {
  /* no styles needed */
}

/* Header 4
Slickest solution with least HTML:
Wrap text that needs italics in <i> and then style lines with CSS
*/
.header4 {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

/* For Demo Purposes */
.dash {
  border-style: dashed;
}

.edge {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: 3px;
}

summary:hover {
  color: lime;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

summary + u {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

code {
  color: green;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  white-space: pre;
}

summary + code {
  display: block;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a:link, 
a:visited {
  color: cyan;
  background: #000;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  color: blue;
  background: none;
}  

a::before {
  content: 'View .'attr(data-tag);
}

a.off::before {
  content: 'Hide .'attr(data-tag);
} 

a::after {
  content: ' HTML';
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.txt {
  color: blue;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<main>
<hr class='edge'>
<details><summary>Header (OP)</summary>
<u>Selector fails -- :not() is prefixed incorrectly
.header:...  means .header is targeted &#128078;
.header<code>&blank;</code>:... means the descendants of .header is targeted &#128077;
There is no .header.A, .header.B, nor .header.A.B so
.header <em>without</em> .A and/or .B will have everything in italics</u></details>
<details><summary>CSS</summary>
<code>.header:not(.A):not(.B) {
  font-style: italic;  
}</code>
<a href='#/' data-tag='header'></a>
</details>
<hr>

<div class='header'>
  <span class="A">LatestFooty.co.uk</span> is currently available for sale, along with:
  <div class="B">
    LatestFootie.com<br> LatestFootie.co.uk
  </div>
</div>

<hr class='edge'>
<details><summary>Header 1</summary>
<u>Best solution with no extra HTML tags:
Assign <code>font-style: normal</code>...
directly (.C1, .D1)
or by class (.N)</u></details>
<details><summary>CSS</summary>
<code>.header1 {
  font-style: italic;
}

.C1,
.D1,
.N {
  font-style: normal;
}</code>
<a href='#/' data-tag='header1'></a>
</details>
<hr>

<div class="header1">
  <span class="C1">LatestFooty.co.uk</span> is currently available for sale, along with:
  <div class="D1">
    LatestFootie.com<br> LatestFootie.co.uk
  </div>
</div>

<hr class='dash'>

<div class="header1">
  <span class="C2 N">LatestFooty.co.uk</span> is currently available for sale, along with:
  <div class="D2 N">
    LatestFootie.com<br> LatestFootie.co.uk
  </div>
</div>

<hr class='edge'>
<details><summary>Header 2</summary>
<u>Using :not() needs extra HTML tag:
Wrap second textnode in an inline or inline-block tag
As content of a descendant tag, the text can be targeted</u></details>
<details><summary>CSS</summary>
<code>.header2 *:not(.E):not(.F) {
  font-style: italic;
}</code>
<a href='#/' data-tag='header2'></a>
</details>
<hr>

<div class='header2'>
  <span class="E">LatestFooty.co.uk</span> <span>is currently available for sale, along with:</span>
  <div class="F">
    LatestFootie.com<br> LatestFootie.co.uk
  </div>
</div>

<hr class='edge'>
<details><summary>Header 3</summary>
<u>Smart solution with extra HTML tag:
Wrap second textnode in <code>&lt;i&gt;</code> or <code>&lt;em&gt;</code></u></details>
<details><summary>CSS</summary>
<code>.header3 {
  /* no styles needed */
}</code>
<a href='#/' data-tag='header3'></a>
</details>
<hr>

<div class='header3'>
  <span class="G">LatestFooty.co.uk</span> <i>is currently available for sale, along with:</i>
  <div class="H">
    LatestFootie.com<br> LatestFootie.co.uk
  </div>
</div>

<hr class='edge'>
<details><summary>Header 4</summary>
<u>Slickest solution with least HTML:
Wrap text that needs italics in <code>&lt;i&gt;</code> and then style lines with CSS</u></details>
<details><summary>CSS</summary>
<code>.header4 {
  white-space: pre-line;
}</code>
<a href='#/' data-tag='header4'></a>
</details>
<hr>

<header class='header4'>LatestFooty.co.uk <i>is currently available for sale, along with:</i>
  LatestFootie.com
  LatestFootie.co.uk
</header>
</main>
```