# Adequate CSS selector 1 nested element up

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using CSS selectors, I would like to, on click of a link, put a box shadow around a div one element up.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="selected_div">
                    <a><p id="click"></p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I do not know which selectors to use. Please enlighten me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?rq=1

Comment: you can use `:target` selector to achieve this..

Comment: CSS won't (shouldn't, at least) detect the click of a link anyway; that would not be separating style from script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you want to do an action based upon a click, it's better to use Javascript anyway. CSS has no parent selector and cannot detect a click. Here is the jQuery solution:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#selected_div a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().css("box-shadow", "2px 2px 3px #fff");
  }
}
```

Remember to include the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style parent objects based on the state of their children (as of CSS3).  This is doable with JS, but not with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Using `:target selector` you can highlight the parent element. Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/najayuqojope/1)**.

**CSS Use Here**

```
:target
{
background-color: gold;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 3px #eee;
}

#selected_div
{
border:1px dashed #cecece;

}
```

**HTML Code Used here.**

```
 <div class="container">
 <div id="selected_div">
     <a href="#selected_div">
          <p id="click">Sample TEXT</p>
    </a>
  This content should be selected.

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great.. Now whats the problem with this approach. Downvoters always explain things why a negative marks for any answers. without any explanation this is not going to help anyone...

Comment: whats wrong with the people here.. Here jquery answer should be acceptable  while other non helping answer getting `+1` voting..