# Styling for div classes based on top div by using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

Hi I have a scenario where I have to style a `h3` element based on parent `div` class

Example:

```
<div class="First">
 <p>This is sample text</p>
</div>
<div class="Second">
 <h3>This is sample header</h3>
</div>
```

Now what I want to do is if there is a `p` tag inside class named First, I want to change the style of `h3` tag of second class.

Comment: with only `css` it cannot be achieved to detect whether `p` is a child of `div.First`. You need to make use of either `javascript` or its library like `jQuery`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Shashank, But is there anyway we can do it only using css like                       div[class="First"] p ~ div[class="Second"] h3
{
   color: red;   
}                                                                                                                        not exactly the above code but something like that where I can indicate that the "First" div is closed.

Comment: But if you want to change HTML structure and put `.Second` in `.First` then you can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/92/

Comment: @Raj001, when you are going down the hierarchy from `div.First` to `p`, then in `CSS` there is no way to refer/target back to the parent. The only way one could do, is by `JavaScript`. In your case, you wish to target the child element of the next `div` and not the `sibling` of the same div. Had it been like, if `h3` was the next sibling of `p` then the CSS approach would have been useful, you can only make it to work by JS itself.

Comment: @NenadVracar, there is no point in giving the response by the `tag` which itself is not there. Please note, only `css` tag is there, if it is possible then only provide him the answer, otherwise suggest him by educating the same.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: **Without altering the HTML, this is currently not possible with CSS alone.**

Further information: The [CSS Selectors Level 4 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/) introduce(d) the new parent selector `$`:

```
$div > p {
    // styles here
}
```

The selector above would target the `div`, *not* the `p`. Of course, only divs, which have a direct `p` child element. Still, this wouldn't help much with further additions and as BoltClock noted, the specs haven't been revised for a couple of years and a parent selector might not even come soon.

Comment: The $ syntax has been gone for years, but more importantly, the selectors-4 WD hasn't been updated since 2013 even though many, *many* changes have been made since, including [removing the "parent selector" altogether](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27983098). I recommend simply not providing samples or referencing the specification at this time. Furthermore, that revision of the specification doesn't define if the $ notation can be used to target the h3 based on the first div - so while you can target the first div, that alone isn't really going to help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is there any way that i could somehow mark the div closed in the css for example                                                        (div[class="First"] p ) ~ div[class="Second"] h3                                        { color: red; }                                                                                            I know that the above syntax is wrong but is there something we can close the div separately.

Comment: See my answer, with pure CSS this is not possible. You need to alter your HTML to be able to do that.