# Select some children if certain child exists at least once

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select only the divs with class c, that have at least one sibling with class b. Here are some examples:

```
// Case1
<div class="a"> 
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>

// Case2
<div class="a"> 
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>

// Case3
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div> //this one
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>

// Case4
<div class="a">
    <div class="c"></div> //this one
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div> //this one
</div>
```

I tried the following rule:

```
.a > .b ~ .c {
  background-color: red;
}
```

It works for case 1 - 3 but in the fourth example the first div with class c is not selected. AFAIK there is no other selector that would help me, so I'm trying my luck here.

PS: The div with class a can have more then 3 children. These are just examples and not actual use cases.

Comment: Maybe something like you want will work in css4, but as I see for now you have to use js to reach something like this.

Comment: @Heidel Correction: CSS selectors level 4. There is no CSS4.

Comment: In the future, may be we will have CSS 4 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot match an element that comes before a sibling element because there is no previous sibling selector, nor can you match a child element of a parent element that contains some other child element because there is no parent-of selector. You're going to need some other workaround that is not based on a selector.

Don't count on this being possible in selectors-4 unless you use JavaScript to match and apply a utility class to those `.c` elements — in which case you can do that today by taking advantage of jQuery's long-standing implementation of `:has()` (which I just wrote about [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421224/does-jquery-support-css4-selectors/36421262#36421262)):

```
$('.a:has(> .b) > .c')
```

Comment: As with everything in jQuery, this selector can be reproduced in vanilla JS which may be favorable if jQuery is not already being used

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS only and you have access to the server side code, you could just add an extra `class` like `.contains-b` to the parent elements or a `data-attribute` like `data-contains="b"` and use it as a selector.

```css
.a[data-contains~=b]  .c {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a" data-contains="b">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>

<div class="a" data-contains="c">
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>

<div class="a" data-contains="b c">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c">this one</div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>

<div class="a" data-contains="b c">
  <div class="c">this one</div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c">this one</div>
</div>
```