# Vanilla JS Selector for an element that has a child element with a certain attribute

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I am trying to build a tab system.  If I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wizard-tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-formstep="step1">Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-formstep="step2">Step 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-formstep="step3">Step 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I get the list item that has an anchor with a data-formstep attribute equal to a certain value?  I am currently using this:

```
document.querySelector('.wizard-tabs > ul > li:has(a[data-formstep="'+newStep+'"])').classList.add("active")
```

But I am getting an error saying:

```
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.wizard-tabs > ul > li:has(a[data-formstep="step1"])' is not a valid selector.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make the selector target the `a`, then `li` you want is the parent -e.g. `document.querySelector('.wizard-tabs > ul > li >a[data-formstep="'+newStep+'"]').parentElement`

Comment: That just seems like an unnecessary extra step.  There's gotta be a way to select the LI based on an attribute of an anchor instead of it.

Comment: but `:has` isn't supported in any browser, so it's actually a necessary extra step - there's no point arguing about what browsers support or don't

Comment: Oh, Ok.  I didn't realize that.  I saw :has() in jquery(which I am trying to use vanilla) and thought that was originally a JS selector.

Comment: [MDN documentation for :has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) - I find MDN documentation very good, because even if firefox doesn't support the feature (yet) MDN will document it as it is an emerging standard

Comment: @JaromandaX https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231430/vanilla-js-selector-for-an-element-that-has-a-child-element-with-a-certain-attri#comment-79427112

Comment: @Jaromanda X: I would not trust MDN for this. No one actually knows the status of :has() in the spec - not even browser vendors themselves, much less the community.

Comment: who would you trust? MDN links to [a draft CSS4 document](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) - would you trust that?

Comment: @Jaromanda X: Yes, because at least the spec is maintained by the working group and not the community.

Answer (score 0):

**`:has` is an experimental technology, it currently has no support in *any* browser.**

See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has
(thanks to @jaromanda-x)

**The fix:**
As Jaromanda said, just reference the `<a>` and then get it's `.parentElement`.

```
var li = document.querySelector('.wizard-tabs > ul > li >a[data-formstep="'+newStep+'"]').parentElement;
```

Comment: `("parent:has(tag)")` is not the same as `('parent>tag').parentElement` `has()` does target all descendants, if it were `has(>tag)` then yes it would be the same.

Comment: however, @Kaiido `("parent:has(tag)")` is the same as `('parent tag')`, and then traversing up the parentElement chain to `parent` ... yes, it's more complex, but in the example given, your point is moot

Answer (score 0):

`:has()` as of 2017 is a non-standard jQuery selector *only*. Its status in the spec is unknown, no implementations exist, and you should *not* assume that it will ever be implemented until it is ready.

There is no equivalent to `:has()` in current selector syntax (which is the entire reason why it was added to the spec); your best bet is selecting the child element itself and using `.parentElement` to get its parent.

Comment: it is currently `an experimental technology` - so, "non-standard" is overstating things

Comment: @Jaromanda X: It's been "experimental" with **no** native implementations for nearly **six years** since the FPWD. These six years have been no different from the past decade that jQuery has been around.

Comment: the linked draft css document is dated `Selectors Level 4
Editor’s Draft, 23 August 2017` - not sure where you get 6 years from - the MDN page has existed only since `Jan 10, 2016, 3:50:50 PM` so ... again .. what are you going on about it being experimental for 6 years? Are you from the future?

Comment: @Jaromanda X: Sorry, I misremembered, [:has() was only added to the spec in 2014/2015, replacing the subject indicator from the FPWD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982922/latest-on-css-parent-selector/27983098#27983098) (which, by the way, means First Public Working Draft). So about three years, not six. My point remains that I would not hold my breath for implementations since no progress has been made whatsoever in those three years (unless you count renaming selector profiles as progress).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very rough polyfill for `has()` selector which would probably need more testings, but that can still be helpful:

```js
(function() {

  // Can probably be improved
  // Will search for sequence ":has(xxx)" even if xxx contains other sets of func(yyy)
  function searchForHas(selector) {
    if (!selector) {return null;}
    const closed = [], valids = [], open = [], lastFour = ['', '', '', ''];

    selector.split('').forEach(char => {
      if (char == ')') {
        closed.push(open.pop()); // close the last open one
      }
      open.forEach(o => o.s += char); // add this char to all open ones
      if (char == '(') {
        open.push({
          s: ''
        }); // open a new one as an object so we can cross reference
        if (lastFour.join('') === ':has') {
          valids.push(open[open.length - 1]); // this one is interesting
        }
      }
      // update our ':has' sequence identifier
      lastFour.shift();
      lastFour.push(char);
    });
    if (!valids.length) {
      return null;
    } else {
      let str = selector.split(':has(' + valids[0].s + ')');
      return [str.shift(), valids[0].s, str.join('')]; // [pre, current_has, post]
    }
  }

  function has(that, sel_parts) {
    const matches = [...that.querySelectorAll(sel_parts[0])] // pre selector
      .filter(el => el.querySelector(sel_parts[1])); // which has one current_has
    return sel_parts[2] ? Array.prototype.concat.apply([], // if there is a post
      matches.map(el => [...el.querySelectorAll(':scope' + sel_parts[2])] // flatten all the matches
        .filter(el => !!el)
      )
    ) : matches;
  }
  // Overwrite the protos
  const dQS = Document.prototype.querySelector;
  Document.prototype.querySelector = function querySelector(selector) {
    const has_parts = searchForHas(selector);
    if (has_parts) {
      return has(this, has_parts)[0] || null;
    } else {
      return dQS.apply(this, [selector]);
    }
  };
  const dQSA = Document.prototype.querySelectorAll;
  Document.prototype.querySelectorAll = function(selector) {
    const has_parts = searchForHas(selector);
    if (has_parts) {
      let arr = has(this, has_parts);
      return arr && arr.length ? arr : null;
    } else {
      return dQSA.apply(this, [selector]);
    }
  };
  const eQS = Element.prototype.querySelector;
  Element.prototype.querySelector = function(selector) {
    const has_parts = searchForHas(selector);
    if (has_parts) {
      return has(this, has_parts)[0] || null;
    } else {
      return eQS.apply(this, [selector]);
    }
  };
  var eQSA = Element.prototype.querySelectorAll;
  Element.prototype.querySelectorAll = function(selector) {
    const has_parts = searchForHas(selector);
    if (has_parts) {
      let arr = has(this, has_parts);
      return arr && arr.length ? arr : null;
    } else {
      return eQSA.apply(this, [selector]);
    }
  };
})();

console.log(document.querySelector('.wizard-tabs > ul > li:has(a[data-formstep="step1"])'));
// and even
console.log(document.querySelector('li:has(a[data-formstep="step2"])>i'));
```

```html
<div class="wizard-tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-formstep="step1">Step 1</a><i data-s="1"></i></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-formstep="step2">Step 2</a><i data-s="2"></i></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-formstep="step3">Step 3</a><i data-s="3"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```