# HTML - Edit/select a parent?

Tags: html, css, parent-child

[image]

The green area, is the area which I can edit and modify in the CMS system, but the red part is out of my control. I want to change some of the flex elements in the class that is circled in blue.

Is there anyway to select a parent starting from the class `.edit-upper-div` ? Like there is to select a child element using `<`

Comment: Cant you just pick the class you want to edit, no matter where it is, redeclare it, and rewrite anything you need using !important ?

Comment: If you can edit the style tag contents then you can style any part of the DOM including the elements in red. Also have a look at the :has pseudo class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982922/latest-on-css-parent-selector

Comment: Look into the `has()` pseudo code.

Comment: @Dave111 The issue is the class that I would redeclare comes up multiple times in the page. And I only want this exact one edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
ul:has(.edit-upper-div) {
  // do your styling here....
}
```