# css selector for a node which doesn't contain a given selector with class attribute

Tags: css

How do I select the entire h4 node that doesn't contain h3 with class="avoid"? In this case I want to select the first and fourth h4 node.

```
<div>
<h4>
    <h1><h1>
    <h2><h2>
</h4>
<h4>
    <h1><h1>
    <h2><h2>
    <h3 class="avoid"><h3>
</h4>
    <h4>
    <h1><h1>
    <h2><h2>
    <h3 class="avoid"><h3>
</h4>
<h4>
    <h1><h1>
    <h2><h2>
</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: the markup is invalid: you cannot insert an heading element inside another heading

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Having heading tags inside another is not valid. Saying that..

> CSS is not capable of selecting a parent based on nested elements.

You need JS to do such selections. A good read is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child).