# CSS how to select each li after the one im hovering, IF i hover over a specific child of that li

Tags: html, css, hover

I've been banging my head against this for a couple hours now. Maybe it can't be done, maybe I've missed something obvious.

I need to highlight the li I'm hovering over, and each li after that but not before, and only if I'm also hovering over a specific child of that li.

So in the code example, if I hover over the second li's div.doAThing, the second through to last li should highlight. I'm not sure how to get the selection working.

```css
li
{
  background-color: #3e3e3e;
}

li:hover, li:hover ~ li
{
  background-color: #aaf500;
}
```

```html
<ul id="theList">
  <li>
    <div>Data</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div class='doAThing'>All</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Data</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div class='doAThing'>All</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Data</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div class='doAThing'>All</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Data</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div class='doAThing'>All</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, it can't be done with only CSS. You need some way to target the parent, which isn't really possible with only CSS. I don't know if your able to use JavaScript/jQuery in your project, but I've put together an example of how you could do it. Basically, when you hover a `.doAThing` element, we add a class `hover` to its parent (the `li`). And then we can easily target those specific elements in a similar way you did in the code you provided. Hope it helps. Please see the following SO links for further information:

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

[Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

```js
$('.doAThing').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
}, function () {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
li {
  background-color: #3e3e3e;
}
.hover, .hover ~ li {
  background-color: #aaf500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="theList">
  <li>
    <div>Data</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div class='doAThing'>All</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Data</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div class='doAThing'>All</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Data</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div class='doAThing'>All</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Data</div>
    <div>One</div>
    <div class='doAThing'>All</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to do it in just CSS, but I'm already using JQuery so this is a short and easy solution. 

Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherRoy Great! Don't forget to accept my answer if it did help you solve your problem.

Comment: Successful workaround, but I changed the .hover class name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i just used child of

```
li:hover > * {
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Hope it helps