# need to style parent element using CSS

Tags: css

I have, e.g.:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```

And with the help of the child element, I need the style parent element.
I have tried: `has()` and `<` (less symbol) but nothing works.
How could I do this?

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/9787228

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. But nothing there works, to be honest. So, I hope there is anoher way

Comment: If It's not working then only you can achieve this using jquery or javascript : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45008/9787228

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: can you give more details please ?

Comment: You can't select parent element using child element in css. this is the limitation of css. You need to use JS for this.

Comment: I have nothing to add, I just need to style parent element using child